# How can I check whether a variable is defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined

How to check whether a JavaScript variable defined in cross-browser way?

I ran into this problem when writing some JavaScript utilizing FireBug logging. I wrote some code like below:

```
function profileRun(f) {
    // f: functions to be profiled
    console.profile(f.constructor);
    f();
    console.profileEnd(f.constructor);
}
```

It works fine in FireFox/FireBug, but it reports error in IE8 RC1. So, I'd like to do some checking whether ***console*** variable exists in the execution environment.

Below code works fine in FireFox, but not in IE8 RC1.

```
function profileRun(f) {
    if (console != undefined) {
        console.profile(f.constructor);
    }

    f();

    if (console != undefined) {
        console.profileEnd(f.constructor);
    }
}
```

However, if I do it this way. It works in IE8 RC1. Why?

```
function profileRun(f) {
    if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.profile(f.constructor);
    }

    f();

    if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.profileEnd(f.constructor);
    }
}
```

Is there any cross-browser way to check it?

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? I don't understand. This question is 2 years older, has more votes and views, and not any worse than the other question.

Comment: That's a good question, @Cruncher - but all things being equal, the other question is *shorter* so I'm merging to preserve the answers and provide a redirect.