# How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I wanted to check whether the variable is defined or not. For example, the following throws a not-defined error

```
alert( x );
```

How can I catch this error?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-to-check-whether-a-javascript-variable-defined/519157#519157](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-to-check-whether-a-javascript-variable-defined/519157#519157)

Comment: Looks like this is a granddaddy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485840/whether-a-variable-is-undefined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null - great gramps maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the marked duplicate. Variable resolution and object property resolution are very different things. A better duplicate is [*how to check if a variable exist in javascript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879319/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exist-in-javascript).

Comment: Your error is due to the variable not being declared. Most answers are focused on assignment. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48181567/4722345) for more. Additionally many of them incorrectly state that null and undefined are objects in JavaScript. They are [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), not objects...

Answer (score 1867, accepted):

In JavaScript, `null` is an object. There's another value for things that don't exist, `undefined`. The DOM returns `null` for almost all cases where it fails to find some structure in the document, but in JavaScript itself `undefined` is the value used.

Second, no, there is not a direct equivalent. If you really want to check for specifically for `null`, do:

```
if (yourvar === null) // Does not execute if yourvar is `undefined`
```

If you want to check if a variable exists, that can only be done with `try`/`catch`, since `typeof` will treat an undeclared variable and a variable declared with the value of `undefined` as equivalent.

But, to check if a variable is declared *and* is not `undefined`:

```
if (yourvar !== undefined) // Any scope
```

Previously, it was necessary to use the `typeof` operator to check for undefined safely, because it was possible to reassign `undefined` just like a variable. The old way looked like this:

```
if (typeof yourvar !== 'undefined') // Any scope
```

The issue of `undefined` being re-assignable was fixed in ECMAScript 5, which was released in 2009. You can now safely use `===` and `!==` to test for `undefined` without using `typeof` as `undefined` has been read-only for some time.

If you want to know if a member exists independent but don't care what its value is:

```
if ('membername' in object) // With inheritance
if (object.hasOwnProperty('membername')) // Without inheritance
```

If you want to to know whether a variable is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

```
if (yourvar)
```

[Source](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20050214/099714.html)

Comment: undefined is not a reserved word; you (or someone else's code) can do "undefined = 3" and that will break two of your tests.

Comment: "If you know the variable exists but don't know if there's any value stored in it" -- huh?!

Comment: I think he is referring to a variable declared that has not been assigned to.  
eg:
var foo;  // foo exists but does not have a value

Comment: Hmmm... I just noticed the "source" link: this entire post is a direct quote from a mailing list, & should probably be edited to make that more clear, as the original author is not available to clarify.

Comment: Also from what I can tell, that section "If you know the variable exists" has no difference from the previous section. The next section ("if you want to know if a member exists independent...") is correct.

Comment: "In JavaScript null is an object.", that's not actually true, and probably, the culprit of this misconception is the `typeof` operator (`typeof null == 'object'`). The [`null` value](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.11) is a [primitive value](http://es5.github.com/#primitive_value), which is the only value of the [Null type](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.12).

Comment: For the global scope case, don't you need to ask `window.hasOwnProperty('varname')`? Otherwise, it might be that `varname` already exists, but somebody has set it to `undefined` for the time being.

Comment: using `if(!!yourvar)` wouldn't be better?

Comment: Why are some of them backwards and forwards? as in `undefined != yourvar` and` window['varname'] != undefined`?

Comment: Is it possible to wrap "typeof yourvar != 'undefined'" into a function of some sort?  I can't even seem to pass 'yourvar' into a function if it is not declared.

Comment: and optional :: check all variable ::

try {
      some_var.xxx.xxx.xxx
      x = 't';
   }catch(e){
      x = 'f';
   }
console.debug(x);

Comment: @MichelAyres why can't I just do `if (yourvar)`

Comment: what do you mean by ` no constant named undefined.`

Comment: @bobobobo "Netscape did not support the typeof operator until Navigator 3…". `void` was introduced in JScript 2.0 and `typeof` in JScript 1.0.

Comment: from w3schools - x === undefined to check undefined variables.

Comment: #1 gotcha in truthiness evaluation (!myVar or == or logic operators) is NaN. NaN does not equal itself. Nor does it loosely evaluate to true or false. If working with something that can return NaN, keep this in mind. Because NaN gets weird. Fortunately it tends to reveal itself (e.g. `NaN && false` returns `NaN`). `isNaN` is the built-in function you want for comparisons.

Comment: undefined as a value goes without apices, so x === undefined

Comment: In JavaScript, to have a variable having `undefined` value is identical to have a variable being undeclared. So, the only real way to check if a variable is not existing is to do a try/catch.

Comment: `undefined` was made to no longer be reassignable several years ago. You can safely check if something is equal or not equal to `undefined` without needing to use `typeof` now

Comment: Right answer and Well Explained

Comment: this condition does not work: if (yourvar !== undefined)

Comment: I still use
```typeof aThing === "undefined"```
because if aThing is truly undefined (i.e. it doesn't exist), then you'll produce an Uncaught ReferenceError which is really bad

Comment: Please note that "undefined" and "not defined" are two different things. The OP asks about "not defined" and this "You can now safely use === and !== to test for undefined" is wrong has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 400):

The only way to truly test if a variable is `undefined` is to do the following. Remember, undefined is an object in JavaScript.

```
if (typeof someVar === 'undefined') {
  // Your variable is undefined
}
```

Some of the other solutions in this thread will lead you to believe a variable is undefined even though it has been defined (with a value of NULL or 0, for instance).

Comment: Because the question was IS NOT UNDEFINED here should be typeof someVar !== 'undefined', right?

Comment: Really, I don't think so that undefinded is an object, check documentation first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: The only test that does not produce a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: This code is correct, but I think saying `undefined` is an object in javascript is misinformation. Does this statement relate to your answer anyway? It is a value `undefined` of type `undefined`, assigned to the global identifier named `undefined`.

Comment: This seems to be a safer answer than the one given by w3schools.com: `(x === undefined)`.  As pointed out in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript#comment-665913), the value of `undefined` could be redefined and that test would fail.  However, using the example given in this answer, that would not be a problem.

Comment: `undefined` is not an object. `typeof null` is `'object'`, while `typeof undefined` is `'undefined'`.

Comment: It's one of the few things in JS that isn't. But `typeof` won't necessarily reveal something isn't an object. Try `6..toString()` in a console to get my meaning.

Comment: @ErikReppen What exactly do you mean by `But typeof won't necessarily reveal something isn't an object`?

Comment: without typeof,
someVar === undefined
should be still fine

Comment: This is now incorrect in terms of it being the only way. `undefined` has been readonly since ES5. You can safely test for undefined using `if (x === undefined) {...}` or using shorthand like this: `if (x === void 0)`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score 77):

Technically, the proper solution is (I believe):

```
typeof x === "undefined"
```

You can sometimes get lazy and use

```
x == null
```

but that allows both an undefined variable x, and a variable x containing null, to return true.

Comment: if you type `var x;` and then `typeof x;` you will get `"undefined"` just like if you did `typeof lakjdflkdsjflsj;`

Comment: So there is no way to check for undefined but declared variable?

Comment: I don't think so; I am not sure why you would want to.

Comment: ujndefined shouldn't be between apices

Comment: what do you mean by apices?

Comment: He meant double-quotes I guess.

Answer (score 19):

An even easier and more shorthand version would be:

```
if (!x) {
   //Undefined
}
```

OR

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined") {
    //Do something since x is defined.
}
```

Comment: the first code-piece can be incorrect if x is being set from a function call.
like x = A();

if A doesnt return anything, it will return "undefined" by default. Doing a !x would be true which would be logically correct. However, if A() returns 0 then !x should be false as x=0. However in JS, !0 is also true.

Comment: the second code can be shortened to: 

    if(!typeof(XX)){ ... }else{ ... }

Comment: @AlejandroSilva Sorry for late reply. That won't work since typeof returns a string, so it will return 'undefined' for an undefined variable, which in turn will evaluate as TRUE therefore leading to a false positive of a defined var.

Comment: Please get rid of the first snippet, it's just bad

Comment: why not x !== undefined ?

Comment: Other comments have pointed out that the first example is bad, but not clearly why. So, for any new coders: !x doesn't test whether x is defined, but whether it's truthy. Strings, boolean true, and positive numbers are all truthy (and I might be forgetting some things), but other potentially valid values like 0, boolean false, and an empty string are not truthy. The first example can work for specific use cases (e.g., testing for a string if you can treat empty the same as undefined), but because of the many where it won't, it should not be considered the default way to check.

Comment: I tried to use if(!x) because it looks so simple... but it doesn't work. The JavaScript stops executing at that point everytime, in all modern browsers. The console shows an error, that x is undefined. Downvoting -1.

Comment: Both of these examples are now wrong. The first one is wrong because that only tests if x is falsey, not undefined. You will enter the `if` block for more values than just `undefined`, such as `null`, `false,` or even `0`. The second example is just out of date now, though wasn't when you wrote it I suppose. `undefined` was made readonly in ES5 and using `typeof` operator is no longer necessary.

Comment: I don't get why this has so many upvotes. The first method is downright not reliable and fails for some valid values (as pointed out by other comments) and the second one is overly complicated. Two terrible methods for something that should just be `if (x !== undefined)`.

Answer (score 16):

I've often done:

```
function doSomething(variable)
{
    var undef;

    if(variable === undef)
    {
         alert('Hey moron, define this bad boy.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider changing "==" to "===". If you call doSomething(null) you will also get the alert. Unless that's what you want.

Comment: Yep.  You have to decide if you want equivalent or exactly equal.  Either case could have a use.

Comment: simplye check like this->    if(typeof variableName !== 'undefined'){ alert(variableName);}

Comment: this is useless since you won't be able to pass an undefined var to a function anyway

Comment: Sure you can.  Try calling a function with no argument.

Comment: Why would you do this rather than just checking against `undefined` itself, or doing it the old way from before `undefined` was read-only using the `typeof` operator? I also have to disagree strongly that `==` has a use .

Comment: JavaScript has evolved a bit in 11 years.

Comment: This doesn't work with undeclared variables, at least in 2020. `doSomething(asdf)
VM1599:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: asdf is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13`

Comment: Mike, it does not work because you have script mode enabled. Its enabled by default if you are using react or similar frameworks.

Answer (score 15):

Sorry for necromancing, but most of the answers here confuse 'undefined' and 'not defined'

1. **Undefined** - a variable is declared but it's value is undefined.
2. **Not defined** - a variable is not even declared.

The only safe way to check for both cases is use `typeof myVar === 'undefined'`

`myVar === undefined` will only check for case number (1). It will still throw "myVar is not defined" for case number (2) if `myVar` is not even declared. The OP specifically asks about the "not even defined" case (2).

<sup>P.S. I do understand that "case 2" is becoming rare in the modern ES6 world, but some old legacy components still live in the past.</sup>

Comment: I prefer this answer over the accepted one

Comment: thanks! i need this case 2 exactly to make my script working in both Windows WSCript.exe and out own application's embedded WSH. I exactly needed to know if `WScript` global object exists or never ever been declared.

Answer (score 5):

The error is telling you that `x` doesn’t even exist! It hasn’t been **declared**, which is different than being **assigned** a value.

```
var x; // declaration
x = 2; // assignment
```

If you declared `x`, you wouldn’t get an error. You would get an alert that says `undefined` because `x` exists/has been declared but hasn’t been assigned a value.

To check if the variable has been declared, you can use `typeof`, any other method of checking if a variable exists will raise the same error you got initially.

```
if(typeof x  !==  "undefined") {
    alert(x);
}
```

This is checking the type of the value stored in `x`. It will only return `undefined` when `x` hasn’t been declared OR if it *has* been declared and was not yet assigned.

Comment: undefined has been readonly since ES5 (2009 release) and you no longer need the `typeof` operator.

Comment: undefined !== not defined, thank you for this answer. If you go if(variable) and its not defined you stil get an error, not with typeof.

Answer (score 5):

The [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator returns `undefined` for any argument/expression passed to it. so you can test against the result (actually some minifiers change your code from `undefined` to `void 0` to save a couple of characters)

For example:

```
void 0
// undefined

if (variable === void 0) {
    // variable is undefined
}
```

Comment: Ding ding! This is the correct answer. Shame it is all the way at the bottom. Everyone is so hung up on still using `typeof` and thinking `undefined` can be reassigned, which hasn't been possible for about a decade.

Comment: This was also safe  before ES5 because back then even if you had reassigned `undefined` ,for God only knows what reason, using `void 0` will always return `undefined` regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like below:

```
function isNotDefined(value) {
  return typeof value === "undefined";
}
```

and call it like:

```
isNotDefined(undefined); //return true
isNotDefined('Alireza'); //return false
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct. Just wanted to add one more option. You also can use `try ... catch` block to handle this situation. A freaky example:

```
var a;
try {
    a = b + 1;  // throws ReferenceError if b is not defined
} 
catch (e) {
    a = 1;      // apply some default behavior in case of error
}
finally {
    a = a || 0; // normalize the result in any case
}
```

Be aware of `catch` block, which is a bit messy, as it creates a block-level scope. And, of course, the example is extremely simplified to answer the asked question, it does not cover best practices in error handling ;).

Answer (score 3):

Another potential "solution" is to use the `window` object. It avoids the reference error problem when in a browser.

```
if (window.x) {
    alert('x exists and is truthy');
} else {
    alert('x does not exist, or exists and is falsy');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the original question at all and is totally irrelevant. Poster was not asking how to test if something is truthy or falsey, he asked how to test for `undefined`. This will not do that.

Comment: Although I agree with Stephen, that this does not actualy anwer the question, it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @ubershmekel, idea to add "window" object helped me. +1

Answer (score 2):

I often use the simplest way:

```
var variable;
if (variable === undefined){
    console.log('Variable is undefined');
} else {
    console.log('Variable is defined');
}
```

**EDIT:**

Without initializing the variable, exception will be thrown "Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined..."

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, wrong! `variable` is defined by `var variable;`. And this snippet will override `variable` in local scope. It can break logic which expects to access a closure or global variable. I.e:
`var variable = 1;
function test() {
    var variable;
    if (variable === undefined){
        console.log('Variable is undefined');
    } else {
        console.log('Variable is defined: ' + variable);
    }    
}
test(); // Variable is undefined`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the ternary conditional-operator:

```js
var a = "hallo world";
var a = !a ? document.write("i dont know 'a'") : document.write("a = " + a);
```

```js
//var a = "hallo world";
var a = !a ? document.write("i dont know 'a'") : document.write("a = " + a);
```

Comment: What if `var a = false;`? You should check that if `a===undefined` instead

Comment: Question: check a not-defined variable..... This is undefined variable: `var x;`  doing above will throw an error

Comment: "If a = false, then it will show "i dont know 'a'"" – That's the problem, the question is to test if it's defined, not whether it's true. If a is defined as false, then a is not undefined. This returns the wrong result in that case. See my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/858270/2055492 for more detail on why this approach doesn't work.

Comment: not only will `!a` test true for `undefined`, it also tests true for `0` and `null` and `false`. This is very incorrect and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

We can check `undefined` as follows

```
var x; 

if (x === undefined) {
    alert("x is undefined");
} else {
     alert("x is defined");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a small function to verify a variable has been declared, which really cuts down on the amount of clutter in my javascript files. I add a check for the value to make sure that the variable not only exists, but has also been assigned a value. The second condition checks whether the variable has also been instantiated, because if the variable has been defined but not instantiated (see example below), it will still throw an error if you try to reference it's value in your code.

Not instantiated - `var my_variable;` Instantiated - `var my_variable = "";`

```
function varExists(el) { 
  if ( typeof el !== "undefined" && typeof el.val() !== "undefined" ) { 
    return true; 
  } else { 
    return false; 
  } 
}
```

You can then use a conditional statement to test that the variable has been both defined AND instantiated like this...

```
if ( varExists(variable_name) ) { // checks that it DOES exist }
```

or to test that it hasn't been defined and instantiated use...

```
if( !varExists(variable_name) ) { // checks that it DOESN'T exist }
```

Comment: Why not return your predicate right away? `return typeof el !== "undefined" && typeof el.val() !== "undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
    // variable is not defined
}
```

**Using the "in" Operator:**

```
if (!('variable' in window)) {
    // variable is not defined
}
```

**Using the "typeof" with "!==":**

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
    // variable is defined
} else {
    // variable is not defined
}
```

**Using a Try-Catch Block:**

```
try {
    // accessing the variable
    var x = variable;
    // If the above line throws a ReferenceError, then the variable is not defined
} catch (e) {
    // variable is not defined
}
```