# Whether a variable is undefined

Tags: jquery

How do I find if a variable is undefined?

I currently have:

```
var page_name = $("#pageToEdit :selected").text();
var table_name = $("#pageToEdit :selected").val();
var optionResult = $("#pageToEditOptions :selected").val();

var string = "?z=z";
if ( page_name != 'undefined' ) { string += "&page_name=" + page_name; }
if ( table_name != 'undefined' ) { string += "&table_name=" + table_name; }
if ( optionResult != 'undefined' ) { string += "&optionResult=" + optionResult; }
```

Comment: undefined is a property of javascript so doesn't need to be in quotes. You're checking to see if the values are actually the string 'undefined'.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp

Comment: @daddywoodland: Little advice; you shouldn't be referencing W3Schools. They are known for giving out false information and isn't a good resource to recommend to others.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid what is wrong with W3Schools? Do you think the link above is incorrect or do you have other examples? I find the a useful reference, obviously not as authoritative as digging through a W3C document but sometimes you just need to quick reference.

Comment: I like to use this function below so I can quickly and easily check the existence of a variable. 
`function doesExist(el) {
  if((typeof el !== "undefined") && (typeof el.val() !== "undefined")){ return true; }
  else{ return false; }
}`
Then you can just call it like this `if (doesExist(variable_name)) { // do stuff }`

Answer (score 328):

jQuery.val() and .text() will never return 'undefined' for an empty selection.  It always returns an empty string (i.e. "").  .html() will return null if the element doesn't exist though.You need to do:

```
if(page_name != '')
```

For other variables that don't come from something like jQuery.val() you would do this though:

```
if(typeof page_name != 'undefined')
```

You just have to use the `typeof` operator.

Comment: if(undefinedVar) will throw an error, but if(someObj.undefinedProperty) will not. In the latter case, you can also skip typeof and use === undefined (or !==), without quotes.

Comment: And I gave you +1 for correctly pointing out that jQuery's methods won't return undefined.

Comment: Yeah.  You're right about the undefined var part.

Comment: typeof is helpful to play with self defined variables, we can whether it is defined or not

Comment: if(typeof page_name != 'undefined') should be if(typeof page_name !== 'undefined')

Answer (score 136):

`if (myVariable === undefined)`

or more precisely

`if (typeof myVariable === 'undefined')`

Note the `===` is used

Comment: Please use `typeof(var) === 'undefined'` as `undefined` is not a constant in JavaScript.

Comment: `typeof` is not a function - please don't use brackets with it.

Comment: so is this answer valid or not? confused by the upvotes and the comments

Comment: @Roy You should go for `if (typeof var === 'undefined')`

Comment: @JonnyReeves I get the following message when applying `typeof(var)`: _Bynary operation argument type string is not compatible with type undefined_

Comment: I upvoted Ascam and was too late to remove my vote :(  turns out 'if (var === undefined)'  work perfectly I tried using 'typeof' and it did not work.

Comment: `if (typeof var === 'undefined')` vs `if (var === undefined)`... Both should work with very subtle differences ***[citation needed]***. Do note the difference of quotes around `undefined` in both use cases which should address the confusion in comments.

Answer (score 3):

http://constc.blogspot.com/2008/07/undeclared-undefined-null-in-javascript.html

Depends on how specific you want the test to be. You could maybe get away with

```
if(page_name){ string += "&page_name=" + page_name; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function my_url (base, opt)
{
    var retval = ["" + base];
    retval.push( opt.page_name ? "&page_name=" + opt.page_name : "");
    retval.push( opt.table_name ? "&table_name=" + opt.table_name : "");
    retval.push( opt.optionResult ? "&optionResult=" + opt.optionResult : "");
    return retval.join("");
}

my_url("?z=z",  { page_name : "pageX" /* no table_name and optionResult */ } );

/* Returns:
     ?z=z&page_name=pageX
*/
```

This avoids using `typeof whatever === "undefined"`. (Also, there isn't any string concatenation.)

Comment: Why is avoiding `typeof ...` a good thing?

Answer (score -7):

You can just check the variable directly. If not defined it will return a [falsy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) value.

```
var string = "?z=z";
if (page_name) { string += "&page_name=" + page_name; }
if (table_name) { string += "&table_name=" + table_name; }
if (optionResult) { string += "&optionResult=" + optionResult; }
```