# jqGrid getCell method returning undefined in IE8

Tags: jqgrid

While using jqGrid's getCell method, it always returns me undefined in IE8. On Mozilla it works fine.

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('getCell',id,column); //returns undefined in IE8 :(
```

Should I use the method defined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579204/470347) instead.

```
function getCellValue(rowId, cellId) {
   var cell = jQuery('#' + rowId + '_' + cellId);        
   var val = cell.val();
   return val;
}
```

What is the best approach?
I have treegrid implemented and am using version 4.3.1 of jqGrid.

My configurations is

```
var grid = $("#grid").jqGrid({
treeGrid: true,
treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
ExpandColumn: 'businessAreaName',
ExpandColClick : true,
url:'agileProgramme/records.do',
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['Id'
          , 'Business Area'
          , 'Investment'
          , 'Org'
          , 'Goal'
],
colModel:[
/*00*/          {name:'agileProgrammeId',index:'agileProgrammeId', width:0, editable:false,hidden:true},
/*01*/          {name:'businessAreaName',index:'businessAreaName', width:160, editable:false},
/*02*/          {name:'programmeName',index:'programmeName', width:150, editable:false, classes:'link'},
/*03*/          {name:'org',index:'org', width:50, editable:false, classes:'orgHierarchy', sortable : false},
/*04*/          {name:'goal',index:'goal', width:70, editable:false}
],
treeReader : {
    level_field: "level",
    parent_id_field: "parent", 
    leaf_field: "leaf",
    expanded_field: "expanded"
},
autowidth: true,
height: 240,
pager: '#pager',
sortname: 'id',
sortorder: "asc",
toolbar:[true,"top"],
caption:"TableGridDemo",
emptyrecords: "Empty records",
jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    page: "page",
    total: "total",
    records: "records",
    repeatitems: false,
    cell: "cell",
    id: "agileProgrammeId"
}
});
```

Thanks Oleg for the response. I found the root cause of the problem. It is in the $.unformat method of jqGrid.

```
 return ret !== undefined ? ret : cnt===true ? $(cellval).text() : $.jgrid.htmlDecode($(cellval).html());
```

I changed it to

```
return (typeof ret != 'undefined') ? ret : cnt===true ? $(cellval).text() : $.jgrid.htmlDecode($(cellval).html());
```

Actually the `ret !== undefined` is not working in ie8. Once, I changed it to `typeof ret != 'undefined'`, it worked like expected.

Comment: Do you try to get the cell value during the cell is in editing mode?

Comment: No all my columns are uneditable.

Comment: `getCell` should work fine in IE8. Would it be possible for you to post a small example of the problem online, such as a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed that you used `getCell` in the wrong place. The most safe place to use `getCell` in in `loadComplete` or inside of some other callback. In case situation you are sure that the data which you try to read are already in jqGrid. IE8 is much slowly as other web browsers so I can only suppose that even you used `getCell` in the wrong place the modern browsers are already read the grid contain and so your tests were successful.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NehuGetCell.htm) I made based on the code which you previously posted. It read 'programmeName' from the first loaded row with respect of `getCell` and display it with respect of `alert`. How you can verify the code works without any problem in IE8.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg for the demo. The demo is working fine in IE8. However, when I paste the same code that you have in the loadComplete method in my jqGrid implementation, it returns me undefined. So, I think the problem lies elsewhere. I will try to debug and let you know once finished.

Comment: Oleg, I got the root cause of the problem. It is in the $.unformat method. I have updated my original question with the answer.

Comment: @Nehu: Could you post the test data which can be used to reproduce the problem. The demo which I posted use `getCell`. Which data should be used to reproduce the problem? Do you overwrite `undefined`?

Comment: Oleg, I only found out that `ret !== undefined` is not working in IE8, but works in Mozilla. From this answer in SO - [whether a variable is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1485852/470347), I replaced the above with `typeof ret != 'undefined'` and it worked. I have seen few more places in jqGrid code which uses variable === undefined, which can also be changed.

Comment: Also, I have few more columns and they are updated via setCell method when the grid is loaded. Then, when I get the value for any Cell usind getCell, the $.unformat method is called, wherein lies the issue

Comment: @Nehu: Could you post *test data* which can be used to reproduce the problem? The main advantage of usage of `typeof ret !== 'undefined'` compared with `ret !== undefined` is that the value of `undefined` can be overwritten. For example you can use `undefined = 123;`. So could you post the test data which one can use to reproduce the problem. It's important to know whether your code or code of jqGrid change the value of  `undefined`.

Comment: I tried your demo independently in IE8 and it worked fine. Then, I embedded your demo in my application and the getCell method broke. So, I think you are right, something in the application or the various jquery plugin I am using is changing the value of `undefined`. I am using the following additional plugins : sparkline, jquery.layout, jquery UI.Also, using DWR... Also, I see that the tree Grid's child Node image changes from the small circle to upper arrow in IE8 when embedded. Your demo independently works perfectly fine. Ill try to find out which plugin or javascript is breaking jqGrid