# How can I determine if a variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, null, undefined

How do I determine if a variable is `undefined` or `null`?

My code is as follows:

```js
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(EmpName == 'undefined'){
  // DO SOMETHING
};
```

```html
<div id="esd-names">
  <div id="name"></div>
</div>
```

But when I do this, the JavaScript interpreter halts execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Use the inbuilt Nullish coalescing operator (??)
Ref;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: if(EmpName == 'undefined') will not test if EmpName is undefined, it will test the string "undefined", so get rid of those single quotes:

if(EmpName == undefined) // because 'undefined'without the quotes is... undefined

or the simpler

if(!EmpName){
  // DO SOMETHING
};

Answer (score 3535, accepted):

You can use the qualities of the [abstract equality operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) to do this:

```
if (variable == null){
    // your code here.
}
```

Because `null == undefined` is true, the above code will catch both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: I'm trying to test if event is null in firefox and an error blocks the execution: "event is undefined"

Comment: Can you share the section of code that's erroring? Use a pastebin link.

Comment: @MichaelFever How does that not work? Copy paste this in your console: `const y = undefined; y == null;` It should return `true`

Comment: `const y = undefined; abc == null;` Will return an error... It seems `undefined` is defined as something...

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski In example from your comment you declared `y` constant, but you ware comparing `abc` (not `y`). When I tested `y` via `console.log(y == null);` on Chrome and Firefox I got `true` as result. If you got error then maybe you tried to use assignment operator `=` instead of comparison `==` which would make sense to return error since `const` can't be reassigned.

Comment: I never suggest to use that kind of comparsion even if it covers two values. Keep using (var === null || var === undefined) instead.

Comment: could be tricky:
  `undefined !== null` --> *true*
  `undefined == null` --> true

Comment: [live example](https://repl.it/@RyanHaining1/nullequalsundefined) of relevant comparisons. lgtm.

Comment: @ZaytsevDmitry why would you expect a test if a variable is `null` or `undefined` to pass if the variable equals `0`? The question is not about testing for a truthy value, but rather, testing explicitly for `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: eslint enforces a rule disallowing this comparison https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-eq-null

Comment: The above code by @Sarfraz throws **"Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined"** !!! How can such an answer be accepted  so widely? Am I the only one in here for whom this simplest of codes doesn't work?

Comment: Because everyone understands that this is a comparison for some variable that you already have declared. The word `variable` is a stand-in for your _actual_ variable. The code shown is a recipe that you adapt to fit your need.

Comment: that doesn't work, `let obj = {};
obj.ha === null \\ return  false`

Comment: @shamaseen Understand the answer. `obj.ha == null`.

Answer (score 1378):

The standard way to catch `null` and `undefined` simultaneously is this:

```
if (variable == null) {
     // do something 
}
```

--which is 100% equivalent to the more explicit but less concise:

```
if (variable === undefined || variable === null) {
     // do something 
}
```

When writing professional JS, it's taken for granted that [type equality and the behavior of `==` vs `===`](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) is understood. Therefore we use `==` and only compare to `null`.

---

### ***Edit again***

The comments suggesting the use of `typeof` are simply *wrong.* Yes, my solution above will cause a ReferenceError if the variable doesn't exist. *This is a good thing.* This ReferenceError is desirable: it will help you find your mistakes and fix them before you ship your code, just like compiler errors would in other languages. Use `try`/`catch` if you are working with input you don't have control over.

**You should not have any references to undeclared variables in your code.**

Comment: This will cause a ReferenceError and break execution if variable is not defined or referred to at all in the code, using typeof is safer.

Comment: That's more of a stylistic point. If the variable hasn't been declared at *all*, that's really just bad writing on the part of the author. You should know whether your variable has been declared or not, that shouldn't be a question. But *yes*, if for *some reason* that's the case, this should be changed to *window.variable* instead of just *variable*, which will not cause a reference error. Typeof should be avoided.

Comment: You forgot many use cases. What about data you get from somewhere else such as url query params or json data from some API? What about dynamic structure? You should be able to test if `data['token']` is defined? By the way, you mentioned Angular Framework but why would Angular define some `angular.isDefined` function if it was useless? Your answer is a bit super strict and lack of pragmatism.

Comment: You don't need `typeof` to check `data['token']` -- that can be done by `if (data.token != null) { /* use data.token */ }` . It's not different. You are, however, right about Angular. They have some very specialized methods in there, like `isBlankObject` and `hasCustomToString`. Evidently they wanted to cover both the case where the variable was `undefined`/`null` as well as undeclared references. While you're correct about their code, for most people this is not what they are looking for, and I stand by my assertion that if you think you need it, you're probably mistaken.

Comment: Yes because you wrote `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: imagine i want to check if load_module_1==1 but the load_module_1 can be undefined because depends on loading ajax. How can in check for its value==1 and does not get the undefined error? in a single line of if(!x){return;}

Comment: @Miguel: Typically, such "possibly declared variables" are globals, i.e. properties of the `window` object, and the standard solution is to refer to them explicitly as such, e.g. `if (! window.load_module_1) return;`.

Comment: One entirely legitimate use case is in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, where the execution of custom scripts is triggered through front end (UI) configuration and variables are passed (or not passed) from a string that is again defined in an input box in the front end.

Comment: -OP: The statement about those comparisons being "100% equivalent" is SIMPLY WRONG, as you noted in your own EDIT, the second will cause a ReferenceError.  As for the assertion: "You should not have any references to undeclared variables in your code."  REALLY?  Ever heard of Optional Parameters?  https://jsfiddle.net/3xnbxfsu/

Comment: @TimothyKanski optional parameters may be undefined if they are optionally not provided, but they are most definitely declared variables. They are declared and have a value of `undefined`, as any declared but uninitialized variable would, ie `var someVar;` so your argument doesn't really hold up

Comment: @chiliNUT I gave up on arguing with the people who still comment on this. Once a year or so I ask a mod to clean up comments. There have been so, so many people trying to convince me this is wrong. It never ends.

Comment: @Aerovistae word, lol with a language like JS with 8 gazillion people of all coding levels and backgrounds trying to program it I doubt there will be an end to comments supporting bad practice or outright faulty understanding of a concept like an undeclared variable, which would throw a compiler error in other popular statically typed languages but is capable of just being "smoothed over" in a dynamic language like JS

Comment: which is just to say, its a common thing for languages with a low cost of entry like javascript and php vs one where you need a more intricate understanding of how a language works before you can really program in it, such as, say, Haskell or Scala

Comment: You say "You should not have any references to undeclared variables in your code" but you forget you need to parse service calls which might, or might not declare properties. Someone needs to know if someRemoteObjectReceived.randomProperty is not received at all, null, undefined, true, "true", "false", false, 1 or 0 depending of a series of uncontrollable events.

Comment: And determining that does not require `typeof`. The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275854/is-there-any-way-to-distinguish-between-an-unset-property-and-a-property-set-to/43275887#43275911)  can distinguish between `undefined` and "not received at all," which is certainly impossible with `typeof`. And to distinguish between the other 8 items you listed, only `===` would get the job done. I can't even begin to imagine how you arrived at the conclusion that `typeof` will distinguish between 0 and 1 or true and false but `===` won't.

Comment: @Aerovistae can I use it as - if (variable != null) {} ? will it give the desired result ?

Comment: That conditional would evaluate to true in all cases where the variable is neither `null` nor `undefined`, so if that's what you want then yes, it will gives the desired result. You could test that out pretty easily btw :)

Comment: Can't you just do `if (variable) ` in Javascript? Also, maybe people mean to reference `instanceof` instead of `typeof` -- that is a best practice according to Nicholas Zakas.

Comment: @Thomas `if (variable)` tests truthiness. It would count out `false`, `0`, `NaN`, and an empty string as well as `null` and `undefined`, so it is not the correct answer here. As for `instanceof`, if the questions is "IS THIS VARIABLE NULL OR UNDEFINED?" (perhaps you *want* the value to be `null` or `undefined`...) you cannot ascertain that with `instanceof`, except by checking that the value *isn't* an instance of any other type, which is crazy. So that is also the wrong answer here.

Comment: its better to put undefine in single qoutes, 'undefined' because it will make it more understandable..

Comment: That's explained in the comments above.

Comment: Unless I missed something obvious, having tried this, exactly as written I received "variable is not defined".and the code halted.

Comment: Then I can infer that you copied and pasted my code exactly. This implies to me that you did not realize that `variable` was meant to be replaced with the name of your variable. I think it might be for the best for you to read a basic tutorial on JavaScript.

Comment: @temporary_user_name I feel like your statement 'You should not have any references to undeclared variables in your code' symbolizes the toxicity and the issue of SO which is neglecting various use-case in real life situations. `if ( typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports ) {
    module.exports = myModule;
} else if ( typeof define == 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define( function () { return myModule; } );
} else {
    window.myModule= myModule;
}` If I'm building a library and wanted to support various browsers, I should just give up because you think it's bad?

Comment: SO is to provide references to various users with varying skill level and usecases. It's not your soapbox for asserting which practice is good, if everyone should use functional programming rather than OOP, or whatever. Deadpan stating "X should not be done" is harmful for this community. If you had worded it like "Generally, this would be considered bad practice among others" I would've had no issues.

Comment: @GyuhyeonLee separate browsers should be considered an exception as your code has no influence over what a browser decides to inject. In general, no matter what scripting or coding language you use, it is indeed bad practice to reference undefined variables. JS is just very weird to begin with which doesnt help (for fun, you should watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et8xNAc2ic8)

Comment: _“This ReferenceError is desirable: it will help you find your mistakes and fix them before you ship your code”_  Yeah, going to disagree with this one.  While it's great to aspire to only use variable that exist, that's not always the reality.  Being able to check for undefined/null has legitimate uses, and a multi-line solution with try/catch is not a good answer to this question.  Sorry, null/undefined are part of the language, and can be reasonably expected in real-world use across all the platforms and libraries that use JS, so a non-cumbersome solution is necessary.

Answer (score 298):

Combining the above answers, it seems the most complete answer would be:

```
if( typeof variable === 'undefined' || variable === null ){
    // Do stuff
}
```

This should work for any variable that is either undeclared or declared and explicitly set to null or undefined.  The boolean expression should evaluate to false for any declared variable that has an actual non-null value.

Comment: @Aerovistae I recognize that `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so it doesn't need the parentheses, but I appreciate the parentheses nonetheless - simply for reading clarity.

Comment: what about directly checking if(variable===undefined) instead of using typeof?

Comment: @ArjunU that will cause a ReferenceError if the variable isn't declared. If you don't know whether or not a variable is declared, used the above solution. If you can guarantee that the variable is at least declared, you can use `variable == null`

Comment: This is a better solution because as @Rogue pointed out, the variable might not be declared.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the first conditional a superset of the second one, and therefore the second conditional is superfluous?

Comment: @MarchHo No. The first conditional can be false, and the second conditional can be true. Consider the case when variable is defined and has the value `null`.

Comment: Thanks for using `typeof`. The var == null way does not "catch" both a null and an undefined, so my if/else statement is useless. But when I use `typeof`, my else will get used and I can control the error printout.

Comment: I used just the first part `if( typeof variable === 'undefined'  ){}` since adding the null part would throw a ReferenceError

Answer (score 193):

```
if (variable == null) {
    // Do stuff, will only match null or undefined, this won't match false
}
```

Comment: Just in case anybody thinks this is another half-answer, this actually does work. `undefined` evaluates equal to `null`.

Comment: Failed to me in chrome console... ReferenceError: variable is not defined, so it might work, but not for me...

Comment: It only works for declared variables, not variables that may or may not be declared, which is rarely the case. (You need to use typeof + a null check for that case)

Comment: For some reason JSHint doesn't like this. :(

Comment: Just [figured out](http://www.jshint.com/docs/#options) you can add this comment: `/*jshint eqnull:true */` to the top of your JS document or function, and JSHint will stop warning you about your uses of `== null`.

Comment: as user216441 pointed out this is a nogo for undeclared variables http://jsfiddle.net/U2VHs/3/

Comment: @Aerovistae can you point me to a reference that explicitly states that `==` is broken. The coercive `if(variable == null)` in this answer makes complete sense to me...

Comment: This answer is WRONG. An undefined variable produces `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @user216441 “It only works for declared variables, not variables that may or may not be declared”  So… it doesn't answer the question, which was “How do I determine if variable is **undefined** or null?”  _(It answers the question “How do I determine if known-to-be-defined variable is null?”)_

Answer (score 106):

```
if (typeof EmpName != 'undefined' && EmpName) {
```

will evaluate to true if value is not:

- **null**
- **undefined**
- **NaN**
- **empty string ("")**
- **0**
- **false**

Comment: I think this is a dangerous technique that has spread like wild fire. Because a lot of the variables that are checked could be boolean or numbers. So if the user does not fully understand the consequences, this is no good.

Comment: Please provide a reference of this javascript especification

Comment: This is the same as `if (EmpName)`. If it's `undefined` will be falsy already.

Comment: If variable is not defined. then if(EmpName) will throw error

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I think Rudy might have meant this `var EmpName;  if (EmpName)`. Where the variable is defined but not assigned a value.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam As Aerovistae wrote under "Edit again", you shouldn't be using undefined variables, and throwing an error in this case is good because you'll notice the mistake quickly and fix it.

Comment: @DavidKnipe that will  ReferenceError and break execution if the variable is not defined or referred to at all in the code, using `typeof` is safer.  If its saas then no problem, If its like self hosted application. Fixing a bug is mess.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I think you've misread what I wrote. I agree that leaving out the `typeof` check will cause a ReferenceError if the variable is not declared. The `typeof` check just means that instead of a compile-time error, the expression will simply evaluate to false. This isn't what OP should want - he should want to fix the undeclared variable. So instead of an error which will immediately be found by a developer, you'll get a potentially much more subtle bug which may take some time to debug and may get into production unnoticed. So in this case it's better to let it throw the exception.

Comment: I do believe if(variable === undefined) without the quotes works best for catching any undefined object or primitive before sending it on to other instructions that might crash with it.

Answer (score 56):

Probably the shortest way to do this is:

```
if(EmpName == null) { /* DO SOMETHING */ };
```

Here is proof:

```js
function check(EmpName) {
  if(EmpName == null) { return true; };
  return false;
}

var log = (t,a) => console.log(`${t} -> ${check(a)}`);

log('null', null);
log('undefined', undefined);
log('NaN', NaN);
log('""', "");
log('{}', {});
log('[]', []);
log('[1]', [1]);
log('[0]', [0]);
log('[[]]', [[]]);
log('true', true);
log('false', false);
log('"true"', "true");
log('"false"', "false");
log('Infinity', Infinity);
log('-Infinity', -Infinity);
log('1', 1);
log('0', 0);
log('-1', -1);
log('"1"', "1");
log('"0"', "0");
log('"-1"', "-1");

// "void 0" case
console.log('---\n"true" is:', true);
console.log('"void 0" is:', void 0);
log(void 0,void 0); // "void 0" is "undefined"
```

And here are more details about `==` (source [here](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/))

[image]

**BONUS**: reason why `===` is more clear than `==` (look on [agc answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255870/860099))

[image]

Comment: Thank you, great answer! What about expressions like if(var) or if(!var) ?

Comment: @IceFire example difference: `if(var)/if(!var)` will execute code for values `true/false`. The `if(var == null)` for those values of var NEVER execute code...

Comment: Well, this is trivial, but can one of the matrices above also be used to check what the if expressions yield for different values?

Comment: @IceFire in my answer there is link to source of this picutres - there is also if statement "matrix" there

Answer (score 33):

jQuery `attr()` function returns either a blank string or the actual value (and never `null` or `undefined`). The only time it returns `undefined` is when your selector didn't return any element.

So you may want to test against a blank string. Alternatively, since blank strings, null and undefined are false-y, you can just do this:

```
if (!EmpName) { //do something }
```

Comment: Chrome 17.0.963.78 m gives this error: `ReferenceError: EmpName is not defined`

Comment: @EranMedan I know this is late, but it will hopefully help people who come here later. The reason you get an error is because it has not been declared at all. Usually you'd have EmpName(or some other variable) be passed into a function, or the return value of another function and therefore declared(Example: "var x;"). To test if it returned undefined, or null, or blank string, you can use the above solution.

Comment: I realise this is a cold question, but jQuery will return `undefined` if the attribute doesn't exist on the element (not just just if the selector has no matching elements, as per the answer). For example, an `img` with no `src` would return `undefined` for `$('img').attr('src');`

Answer (score 28):

*Edited answer*: In my opinion, you shouldn't use the function from my below old answer. Instead, you should probably know the type of your variable and use the according to check directly (for example, wondering if an array is empty? just do `if(arr.length===0){}` etc.). This answer doesn't even answer OP's question.

---

I've come to write my own function for this. JavaScript is weird.

It is usable on literally anything. (Note that this also checks if the variable contains any usable *values*. But since this information is usually also needed, I think it's worth posting). Please consider leaving a note.

```
function empty(v) {
    let type = typeof v;
    if (type === 'undefined') {
        return true;
    }
    if (type === 'boolean') {
        return !v;
    }
    if (v === null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (v === undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    if (v instanceof Array) {
        if (v.length < 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (type === 'string') {
        if (v.length < 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (v === '0') {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (type === 'object') {
        if (Object.keys(v).length < 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (type === 'number') {
        if (v === 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

TypeScript-compatible.

---

This function should do *exactly* the same thing like PHP's [`empty()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (see `RETURN VALUES`)

Considers `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`, `0.0`, `"0"` `{}`, `[]` as empty.

`"0.0"`, `NaN`, `" "`, `true` are considered non-empty.

Comment: I have run into a little null checking problem.  I want to check if a parameter being passed is null, or an empty object `{ }`.  This is a common and silly language problem, but I had forgotten about it.  All my searches show answers for undefined of null value, or loose equality comparisons ( == ), but not strict equality ( === ) or equivalent.  And then here in your -1 ranked answer at the **very bottom** of the page (before I upvoted) is the answer that eluded me.  `Object.keys( obj ).length < 1` or maybe === 0, assuming it will never be -1.  Anyways, upvoted to 0, woo.  :p

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to drop this function in and clean up a lot of code. Why this isn't a standard JS function is beyond me.

Comment: You should change *all* of your ```==``` to ```===``` here, then this would be a reasonable function.

Answer (score 24):

**The shortest and easiest:**

```
if(!EmpName ){
 // DO SOMETHING
}
```

this will evaluate true if EmpName is:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty
- string ("")
- 0
- false

Comment: Use case here is that I want to know the difference between undefined and false. I will use the check on null then.

Answer (score 15):

If the variable you want to check is a global, do

```
if (window.yourVarName) {
    // Your code here
}
```

This way to check will not throw an error even if the `yourVarName` variable doesn't exist.

### Example: I want to know if my browser supports History API

```
if (window.history) {
    history.back();
}
```

### How this works:

`window` is an object which holds all global variables as its properties, and in JavaScript it is legal to try to access a non-existing object property. If `history` doesn't exist then `window.history` returns `undefined`. `undefined` is falsey, so code in an `if(undefined){}` block won't run.

Comment: Readers should note that an approach like this is idiomatic for checking - from JavaScript running in a browser - whether a *global* variable has been declared, and especially whether a browser-provided global (like the history API) is available. It *will not work* for checking whether a non-global variable is `null` or `undefined`, nor will it work if your JavaScript is running outside a browser (i.e. in Node.js). It will also treat globals set to `0`, `false` or `''` the same as those which are undeclared or `undefined` or `null`, which is usually fine.

Comment: This assumes that the script is running in a browser.   That's not a given.

Answer (score 13):

In **JavaScript**, as per my knowledge, we can check an **undefined**, **null** or **empty** variable like below.

```
if (variable === undefined){
}

if (variable === null){
}

if (variable === ''){
}
```

**Check all conditions:**

```
if(variable === undefined || variable === null || variable === ''){
}
```

Comment: `var` is a reserved word, this will throw `SyntaxError`

Comment: @dhilt implemented from var to variable

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using **jQuery**, you can determine whether a variable is undefined or its value is null by using a single function.

```
var s; // undefined
jQuery.isEmptyObject(s); // will return true;

s = null; // defined as null
jQuery.isEmptyObject(s); // will return true;

// usage
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(s)){
    alert('Either variable: s is undefined or its value is null');
}else{
     alert('variable: s has value ' + s);
}

s = 'something'; // defined with some value
jQuery.isEmptyObject(s); // will return false;
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I still got the error: `ReferenceError: s is not defined` for the first example.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use the following (I know there are shorter ways to do this, but this may make it easier to visually observe, at least for others looking at the code).

```
if (x === null || x === undefined) {
 // Add your response code here, etc.
}
```

source: https://www.growthsnippets.com/how-can-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-undefined-or-null/

Answer (score 9):

I've just had this problem i.e. checking if an object is null.
I simply use this:

```
if (object) {
    // Your code
}
```

For example:

```
if (document.getElementById("enterJob")) {
    document.getElementById("enterJob").className += ' current';
}
```

Comment: it would be better to set var A = document.getElementById("enterJob")

if(A)A.className+= ' current';

this way you do 50% work for same result... But maybe you just did it for shows and then I salute.

Answer (score 7):

With the newest javascript changes, you can use the new logical operator `??=` to check if the left operand is `null` or `undefined` and if so assign the value of right operand.

SO,

```
if(EmpName == null){  // if Variable EmpName null or undefined
  EmpName = 'some value';
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
EmpName ??= 'some value';
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery check element not null:

```
var dvElement = $('#dvElement');

if (dvElement.length  > 0) {
    // Do something
}
else{
    // Else do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to check is:

```
if(!variable) {
  // If the variable is null or undefined then execution of code will enter here.
}
```

Comment: This will execute the code if the variable has a value of `false`, which is potentially undesirable.

Comment: The question is clear "How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?" and in javascript if a variable has a value of null or undefined,its value is false.

Comment: Sorry, but that's incorrect. Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5ynkav3/) to prove it.

Comment: By your answer, `undefined`, `null` **and** a few other things like empty string, +0, -0 `NaN` and `false` get through. `!` operator coerces the operand- here `variable`- to Boolean: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toboolean

Comment: But check the question: "How to determine if a variable is undefined or null", the ! operand used with an if will always return to true if the variable is null or undefined.

Answer (score 4):

No one seems to have to posted this yet, so here we go:

`a?.valueOf() === undefined` works reliably for either `null` or `undefined`.

The following works pretty much like `a == null` or `a == undefined`, but it could be more attractive for purists who don't like `==`

```js
function check(a) {
  const value = a?.valueOf(); 
  if (value === undefined) {
    console.log("a is null or undefined");
  }
  else {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

check(null);
check(undefined);
check(0);
check("");
check({});
check([]);
```

On a side note, `a?.constructor` works too:

```js
function check(a) {
  if (a?.constructor === undefined) {
    console.log("a is null or undefined");
  }
}

check(null);
check(undefined);
check(0);
check("");
check({});
check([]);
```

---

**Updated**: we worked out [a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-can-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-undefined-or-null/76360760?noredirect=1#comment134659061_76360760) with a fellow StackOverflow member.

I'd personally do:

```
if (Object.is(a ?? null, null)) {
  // a is null or undefined
}
```

Comment: _“`a?.valueOf() === undefined` works reliably”_…. Uh, `a = {valueOf() {}}`.

Comment: Yeah you should have also mentioned `a = Object.create(null)`, which could be a less silly but equally useless thing. It isn't a bug a human could introduce by mistake, it has to be done on purpose. Otherwise, yes, it's JavaScript and you can hack it however you want.

Answer (score 3):

I run this test in the Chrome console. Using (void 0) you can check undefined:

```
var c;
undefined
if (c === void 0) alert();
// output =  undefined
var c = 1;
// output =  undefined
if (c === void 0) alert();
// output =   undefined
// check c value  c
// output =  1
if (c === void 0) alert();
// output =  undefined
c = undefined;
// output =  undefined
if (c === void 0) alert();
// output =   undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

With the solution below:

```
const getType = (val) => typeof val === 'undefined' || !val ? null : typeof val;
const isDeepEqual = (a, b) => getType(a) === getType(b);

console.log(isDeepEqual(1, 1)); // true
console.log(isDeepEqual(null, null)); // true
console.log(isDeepEqual([], [])); // true
console.log(isDeepEqual(1, "1")); // false
etc...
```

I'm able to check for the following:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty
- string ("")
- 0
- false

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is "how do I catch null and undefined?" not "how do I catch every falsey value in JavaScript?"

Comment: @Aerovistae, I thought I did with console.log(isDeepEqual(null, null)); and console.log(isDeepEqual(undefined, undefined)); ?

Answer (score 3):

if you create a function to check it:

```js
export function isEmpty (v) {
 if (typeof v === "undefined") {
   return true;
 }
 if (v === null) {
   return true;
 }
 if (typeof v === "object" && Object.keys(v).length === 0) {
   return true;
 }

 if (Array.isArray(v) && v.length === 0) {
   return true;
 }

 if (typeof v === "string" && v.trim().length === 0) {
   return true;
 }

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To test if a variable is null or undefined I use the below code.

```
    if(typeof sVal === 'undefined' || sVal === null || sVal === ''){
      console.log('variable is undefined or null');
    }
```

Comment: Close but no. Lose the `typeof` and compare to `undefined` straight out, not as a string. This works but the extra operator has no effect but to make it wordier.

Comment: In this case yes you are right we don't need to use typeof. But it's a good practice to use typeof when you are dealing with undefined variables. One reason to use typeof is that it does not throw an error if the variable has not been declared.

Comment: That's actually a bad thing. You don't want undeclared variables in your code. You want that to throw a ReferenceError so you can find the variable and declare it. Certainly you wouldn't try that in a compiled language like C++! Just because JS allows it doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: Your or statement is backwards. Checking that something is undefined would be the first step, not the second.

Answer (score 2):

```
(null == undefined)  // true

(null === undefined) // false
```

Because === checks for both the type and value. Type of both are different but value is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this,

1. ```
   let apple; // Only declare the variable as apple
   alert(apple); // undefined
   ```

   In the above, the variable is only declared as `apple`. In this case, if we call method `alert` it will display undefined.
2. ```
      let apple = null; /* Declare the variable as apple and initialized but the value is null */
      alert(apple); // null
   ```

In the second one it displays null, because variable of `apple` value is null.

So you can check whether a value is undefined or null.

```
if(apple !== undefined || apple !== null) {
    // Can use variable without any error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `foo == null` check should do the trick and resolve the "undefined OR null" case in the shortest manner. (Not considering "foo is not declared" case.) But people who are used to have 3 equals (as the best practice) might not accept it. Just look at [eqeqeq](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/eqeqeq.js) or [triple-equals](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/triple-equals/) rules in eslint and tslint...

The explicit approach, when we are checking if a variable is `undefined` or `null` separately, should be applied in this case, and my contribution to the topic (27 non-negative answers for now!) is to use `void 0` as both short and safe way to perform check for `undefined`.

Using `foo === undefined` is not safe because undefined is not a reserved word and can be shadowed ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)). Using `typeof === 'undefined'` check is safe, but if we are not going to care about foo-is-undeclared case the following approach can be used:

```js
if (foo === void 0 || foo === null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, I think its more efficient for multiple value check on the same variable in one condition

```
const x = undefined;
const y = null;
const z = 'test';

if ([undefined, null].includes(x)) {
  // Will return true
}

if ([undefined, null].includes(y)) {
  // Will return true
}

if ([undefined, null].includes(z)) {
  // Will return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `(value ?? null) === null` as well if you’d like to stick with the `===` operator and *clarify* the code.

---

So, three ways, so far.

- `value == null`
- `value === null || value === undefined`
- `(value ?? null) === null`

I usually avoid `==`, but this time, I’d prefer `== null`.

Comment: @noseratio-opentowork Well, you negate that and it’ll work.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you need `Symbol()`❓ Why not just `(a ?? null) === null` ❓ Or, `(a ?? undefined) === undefined` ❓

Comment: @noseratio-opentowork Thank you for pointing it out. I unnecessarily overcomplicated it and I don’t understand myself when I wrote it either. Maybe I was tried to check if it was coalesced into the second operand.

Answer (score 0):

Calling typeof null returns a value of “object”, as the special value null is considered to be an empty object reference. Safari through version 5 and Chrome through version 7 have a quirk where calling typeof on a regular expression returns “function” while all other browsers return “object”.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;
if (x === undefined) {
    alert ("only declared, but not defined.")
};
if (typeof y === "undefined") {
    alert ("not even declared.")
};
```

You can only use second one: as it will check for both definition and declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;

if (i === null || typeof i === 'undefined') {
    console.log(i, 'i is undefined or null')
}
else {
    console.log(i, 'i has some value')
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user enters the word 'undefined' ?

Comment: Your question is good, it show condition is true so that we need to change the option normal undefined into typeof condition. @Chuck

Comment: This is wrong. `typeof` will never yield `undefined`, only the string `'undefined'`. Moreover, `i == null` is already true if `i` is `undefined`, so the second boolean would be redundant even if it worked.

Comment: This solution (with the conditions reversed) was already provided by @jkindwall on Oct 11, 2013. stackoverflow.com/a/19323555/2943403 This code-only post is completely useless because it adds no new value to the page. In fact, it is adding page bloat and wasting researchers time reading it. Please remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still think the best/safe way to test these two conditions is to cast the value to a string:

```
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');

// Undefined check
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(EmpName) === '[object Undefined]'){
    // Do something with your code
}

// Nullcheck
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(EmpName) === '[object Null]'){
    // Do something with your code
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you believe this is the "best/safe way" to perform the tests?

Comment: Because the conversion is always returning a "standardized" string (i.e. [object Undefined]), so you don't get into trouble by testing falsy values. That's just my opinion based on experiences I had with truthy/falsy values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm not criticizing, its an interesting answer, I just wanted you to provide some explanation for others as to why this is potentially superior to other methods.

Comment: No worries! I had a lot of issues with this type of comparisons, and until now, I find it as the most useful approach for this matter.

Answer (score -2):

Best way:

```
if(typeof variable==='undefined' || variable===null) {

/* do your stuff */
}
```

Comment: This exact solution was already provided by @jkindwall on Oct 11, 2013. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323555/2943403 This code-only post is completely useless because it adds no new value to the page.  In fact, it is adding page bloat and wasting researchers time reading it.  Please remove this answer.

Answer (score -4):

You can check if the value is undefined or null by simply using typeof:

```
if(typeof value == 'undefined'){
```

Comment: See comments in the previous answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273362/6305294) regarding typeof.

Comment: This is incorrect. Does not catch `null`. I do not understand why new, incorrect answers are being provided to a question that was given a correct and complete answer many years ago. Do you feel the current answers are somehow insufficient?

Answer (score -13):

Simplest answer:

```
if(!EmpName){
  // DO SOMETHING
};
```

Comment: This way, you target also falsy values such as `0` or `''`, whereas we want to target only `nullish`/`undefined` values