# Checking something isEmpty in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if a variable is empty in Javascript?

```
if(response.photo) is empty {
    do something
else {
    do something else
}
```

`response.photo` was from JSON, and it could be empty sometimes, empty data cells! I want to check if it's empty.

Comment: What does "empty" mean here? If you're not sure, show us some code.

Comment: Do you mean if it is uninitialized yet?

Comment: Do you mean whether it evaluates to `false`?

Comment: Do you mean if it is the empty string?

Comment: Here is a JavaScript implementation of `PHP`s `empty()` function, in a more readable way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33319704/3779853

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If you're testing for an empty string:

```
if(myVar === ''){ // do stuff };
```

If you're checking for a variable that has been declared, but not defined:

```
if(myVar === null){ // do stuff };
```

If you're checking for a variable that may not be defined:

```
if(myVar === undefined){ // do stuff };
```

If you're checking both i.e, either variable is null or undefined:

```
if(myVar == null){ // do stuff };
```

Comment: Don't use the `undefined` "constant", as it's not a constant at all. Use `typeof myVar === 'undefined'` instead.

Comment: Nope.  If a variable has been declared but not defined it is not null... it is undefined.  If you check for a variable that has not been declared, you'll get a runtime error.  Also, `var undefined = 1;` will break your third example.  Always use `typeof` and check for `"undefined"`.

Comment: @Jhon Woodwrick: That would be the first case, empty string.

Comment: `if(typeof variable === "undefined")`

Comment: Thanks for u help

Comment: What happens in case you use more than 1 whitespace (spacebar)? I mean...the first scenario does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: What about `jQuery.isEmptyObject`?

Comment: Building on top of javascript auto coercion and checking only primitives but consider 0 a valid value it just as simple as `if(!myVar && myVar !==0)`. For a more robust function see my answer below

Answer (score 62):

This is a bigger question than you think. Variables can empty in a lot of ways. Kinda depends on what you need to know.

```
// quick and dirty will be true for '', null, undefined, 0, NaN and false.
if (!x) 

// test for null OR undefined
if (x == null)  

// test for undefined OR null 
if (x == undefined) 

// test for undefined
if (x === undefined) 
// or safer test for undefined since the variable undefined can be set causing tests against it to fail.
if (typeof x == 'undefined') 

// test for empty string
if (x === '') 

// if you know its an array
if (x.length == 0)  
// or
if (!x.length)

// BONUS test for empty object
var empty = true, fld;
for (fld in x) {
  empty = false;
  break;
}
```

Comment: @Tomalak Oops, thanks. I think the triple equals is optional though.  Type of will return a string, nothing will be coerced.

Comment: That's true. Anyway the identity check does not hurt, I guess. :-)

Comment: (!x) will also be true for NaN and []. (x == null) is a test for null or undefined.

Comment: Right, I forgot about NaN. I didn't realize that the test for null worked the same as the test for undefined. `!x` is not true for an empty array though.

Answer (score 16):

This should cover all cases:

```
function empty( val ) {

    // test results
    //---------------
    // []        true, empty array
    // {}        true, empty object
    // null      true
    // undefined true
    // ""        true, empty string
    // ''        true, empty string
    // 0         false, number
    // true      false, boolean
    // false     false, boolean
    // Date      false
    // function  false

        if (val === undefined)
        return true;

    if (typeof (val) == 'function' || typeof (val) == 'number' || typeof (val) == 'boolean' || Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Date]')
        return false;

    if (val == null || val.length === 0)        // null or 0 length array
        return true;

    if (typeof (val) == "object") {
        // empty object

        var r = true;

        for (var f in val)
            r = false;

        return r;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think a empty GUID would pass this test.

Answer (score 6):

I see potential shortcomings in many solutions posted above, so I decided to compile my own.
**Note:** it uses [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), check your browser support.

Solution below considers variable empty if one of the following is true:

1. JS thinks that variable is equal to `false`, which already covers many things like `0`, `""`, `[]`, and even `[""]` and `[0]`
2. Value is `null` or it's type is `'undefined'`
3. It is an empty Object
4. It is an Object/Array consisting **only** of values that are empty themselves (i.e. broken down to primitives each part of it equals `false`). Checks drill recursively into Object/Array structure.
   E.g.

   ```
   isEmpty({"": 0}) // true
   isEmpty({"": 1}) // false
   isEmpty([{}, {}])  // true
   isEmpty(["", 0, {0: false}]) //true
   ```

Function code:

```
/**
 * Checks if value is empty. Deep-checks arrays and objects
 * Note: isEmpty([]) == true, isEmpty({}) == true, isEmpty([{0:false},"",0]) == true, isEmpty({0:1}) == false
 * @param value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isEmpty(value){
  var isEmptyObject = function(a) {
    if (typeof a.length === 'undefined') { // it's an Object, not an Array
      var hasNonempty = Object.keys(a).some(function nonEmpty(element){
        return !isEmpty(a[element]);
      });
      return hasNonempty ? false : isEmptyObject(Object.keys(a));
    }

    return !a.some(function nonEmpty(element) { // check if array is really not empty as JS thinks
      return !isEmpty(element); // at least one element should be non-empty
    });
  };
  return (
    value == false
    || typeof value === 'undefined'
    || value == null
    || (typeof value === 'object' && isEmptyObject(value))
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice. You could point out the differences and how it meets the shortcomings that you identified as well.

Comment: I would need to iterate through all decisions here. Ok. As compared to @victorkohl and @kapa functions mine can go deeper than first level and report complex objects that look non-empty but really consist of only empty-like values. Example: `[{},0,""]`.  
All other solutions here are merely two-liners that don't go the distance and an underscore function that works for Objects and requires the lib.

Answer (score 4):

Here my simplest solution.

> Inspired by **PHP** `empty` function

```js
function empty(n){
 return !(!!n ? typeof n === 'object' ? Array.isArray(n) ? !!n.length : !!Object.keys(n).length : true : false);
}

//with number
console.log(empty(0));        //true
console.log(empty(10));       //false

//with object
console.log(empty({}));       //true
console.log(empty({a:'a'}));  //false

//with array
console.log(empty([]));       //true
console.log(empty([1,2]));    //false

//with string
console.log(empty(''));       //true
console.log(empty('a'));      //false
```

Answer (score 4):

A more readable version of [@SJ00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61186802/443431) answer:

```js
/**
 * Checks if a JavaScript value is empty
 * @example
 *    isEmpty(null); // true
 *    isEmpty(undefined); // true
 *    isEmpty(''); // true
 *    isEmpty([]); // true
 *    isEmpty({}); // true
 * @param {any} value - item to test
 * @returns {boolean} true if empty, otherwise false
 */
function isEmpty(value) {
    return (
        value === null || // check for null
        value === undefined || // check for undefined
        value === '' || // check for empty string
        (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) || // check for empty array
        (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0) // check for empty object
    );
}
```

Comment: This will declare a Date object as empty

Answer (score 3):

See http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty

isEmpty_.isEmpty(object) 
Returns true if an enumerable object contains no values (no enumerable own-properties). For strings and array-like objects _.isEmpty checks if the length property is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Combining answers from @inkednm into one function:

```
   function isEmpty(property) {
      return (property === null || property === "" || typeof property === "undefined");
   }
```

Comment: Use `property == null` for combined check on `null` and `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Empty check on a JSON's key depends on use-case. For a common use-case, we can test for following:

1. Not `null`
2. Not `undefined`
3. Not an empty String `''`
4. Not an empty Object `{}` `[]` *(Array is an Object)*

Function:

```js
function isEmpty(arg){
  return (
    arg == null || // Check for null or undefined
    arg.length === 0 || // Check for empty String (Bonus check for empty Array)
    (typeof arg === 'object' && Object.keys(arg).length === 0) // Check for empty Object or Array
  );
}
```

Return true for:

```js
isEmpty(''); // Empty String
isEmpty(null); // null
isEmpty(); // undefined
isEmpty({}); // Empty Object
isEmpty([]); // Empty Array
```

Answer (score 2):

just put the variable inside the if condition, if variable has any value it will return true else false.

```
if (response.photo){ // if you are checking for string use this if(response.photo == "") condition
 alert("Has Value");
}
else
{
 alert("No Value");
};
```

Comment: This assumes 'empty' means null... but it's not clear from the Asker's question that this is what they meant. It's probably better to clarify that first, before offering an answer, or at least state it as an assumption in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
const isEmpty = value => {
  if (!value && value !== 0) return true
  if(Array.isArray(value)){
    if(!value.length) return true
    return value.every(isEmpty)
  }
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    return Object.values(value).every(isEmpty)
  }
  return false
}

isEmpty(); // true
isEmpty(undefined); // true
isEmpty(null); // true
isEmpty(0); // false
isEmpty(1); // false
isEmpty(''); // true
isEmpty('a'); // false
isEmpty([]); // true
isEmpty([0]); // false
isEmpty([1]); // false
isEmpty([[]]); // true
isEmpty([[], []]); // true
isEmpty([[], null, undefined]); // true
isEmpty([[], 1]); // false
isEmpty({}); // true
isEmpty({a: 1}); // false
isEmpty({a: 1, b: 2}); // false
isEmpty({a: 1, b: {}}); // false
isEmpty({a: null, b: [], c: undefined}); // true
isEmpty({a: {}, b: {}, c: {}}); // true
isEmpty(() => {}) // false
```

Comment: If you also want to consider any `Boolean` as not empty (e.g.:explicit `false`) you can modify the first condition to `if (!value && value !== 0 && typeof value !== 'boolean') return true`

Answer (score 1):

Check for undefined:

```
if (typeof response.photo == "undefined")
{
    // do something
}
```

This would do the equivelant of vb's `IsEmpty`.  If myvar contains any value, even null, empty string, or 0, it is not "empty".

To check if a variable or property exists, eg it's been declared, though it may be not have been defined, you can use the `in` operator.

```
if ("photo" in response)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing like this.

`JSON.stringify({}) === "{}"`

Answer (score 1):

just be careful with all what i see here:

`typeof object === 'object' && Object.keys(object).length === 0)` is indeed checking if an object is Empty. But did you know that `Date` in javascript are considered object also?

so if you do:

```js
const shouldNotbeEmpty = new Date(Date.now())
isEmpty(shouldNotbeEmpty) // this will return true when it should not
```

my only way to figure it out to fix that was to check if the object is a Date instance:

`typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0 && !value instanceof Date`

so something like this:

```js
const isObject = value => typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0
const isString = value => typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0
const isEmpty = value => {
  const isDate = value instanceof Date
  return value === undefined || value === null || (isObject(value) && !isDate) || isString(value)
}

exports.isEmpty = isEmpty
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "empty".  The most common pattern is to check to see if the variable is [undefined](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp).  Many people also do a null check, for example:
`if (myVariable === undefined || myVariable === null)...`

or, in a shorter form:
`if (myVariable || myVariable === null)...`

Comment: Don't use the `undefined` "constant", as it's not a constant at all. Use `typeof myVar === 'undefined'` instead.

Comment: These two forms are not the same at all.

Comment: True, there is an undefined type, but to quote the standard: A Reference  is a resolved name binding. A Reference consists of three components, the  base  value, the 
referenced name and the Boolean valued strict reference flag. The base value is either undefined, an Object, a 
Boolean, a String, a Number, or an environment record (10.2.1). A base value of undefined indicates that the 
reference could not be resolved to a binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myVar == undefined)
```

will work to see if the var is declared but not initalized.

Comment: This is dangerous since `undefined` can be redefined in code (i.e. `undefined = true` is valid).

Comment: Don't use the `undefined` "constant", as it's not a constant at all. Use `typeof myVar === 'undefined'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the equivalent of PHP's `empty` function, check this out:

```
function empty(mixed_var) {
  //   example 1: empty(null);
  //   returns 1: true
  //   example 2: empty(undefined);
  //   returns 2: true
  //   example 3: empty([]);
  //   returns 3: true
  //   example 4: empty({});
  //   returns 4: true
  //   example 5: empty({'aFunc' : function () { alert('humpty'); } });
  //   returns 5: false

  var undef, key, i, len;
  var emptyValues = [undef, null, false, 0, '', '0'];

  for (i = 0, len = emptyValues.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (mixed_var === emptyValues[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  if (typeof mixed_var === 'object') {
    for (key in mixed_var) {
      // TODO: should we check for own properties only?
      //if (mixed_var.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return false;
      //}
    }
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

http://phpjs.org/functions/empty:392

Answer (score 0):

what am I missing if empty array... keyless object... falseness
const isEmpty = o => Array.isArray(o) && !o.join('').length || typeof o === 'object' && !Object.keys(o).length || !(+value);

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler(short) solution to check for empty variables. This function checks if a variable is empty. The variable provided may contain mixed values (null, undefined, array, object, string, integer, function).

```
function empty(mixed_var) {
 if (!mixed_var || mixed_var == '0') {
  return true;
 }
 if (typeof mixed_var == 'object') {
  for (var k in mixed_var) {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

//   example 1: empty(null);
//   returns 1: true

//   example 2: empty(undefined);
//   returns 2: true

//   example 3: empty([]);
//   returns 3: true

//   example 4: empty({});
//   returns 4: true

//   example 5: empty(0);
//   returns 5: true

//   example 6: empty('0');
//   returns 6: true

//   example 7: empty(function(){});
//   returns 7: false
```

Comment: Weird... I haven't seen this solution posted online yet but the use of the "!" should take care of checking most values

Answer (score 0):

`const isEmpty = val => val == null || !(Object.keys(val) || val).length;`

Comment: I don't understand, the user asked how to check for empty in javascript, so I assume user knows javascript, no need to explain my answer if the syntax is known?

Comment: Adding a few more words of description will be better (:  
Maybe other people want also to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isEmpty(variable) {
  const type = typeof variable
  if (variable === null) return true
  if (type === 'undefined') return true
  if (type === 'boolean') return false
  if (type === 'string') return !variable
  if (type === 'number') return false
  if (Array.isArray(variable)) return !variable.length
  if (type === 'object') return !Object.keys(variable).length
  return !variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
function isEmpty(object) {
  return (
    (!object)
    || (object === undefined)
    || (object === null)
    || (object === '')
    || ((object?.length !== undefined) && (object.length === 0))
    || (typeof object === 'object' && Object.keys(object).length === 0) 
  );
}
```

Tests with Jest:

```js
describe('isEmpty should return `false` when the parameter have some truthy value.', () => {
  test('Empty objects should return true', () => {
    expect(utils.isEmpty([])).toBe(true);
    expect(utils.isEmpty({})).toBe(true);
    expect(utils.isEmpty('')).toBe(true);
    expect(utils.isEmpty(undefined)).toBe(true);
    expect(utils.isEmpty(null)).toBe(true);
  });

  test('Truthy objects should return false', () => {
    expect(utils.isEmpty([1])).toBe(false);
    expect(utils.isEmpty({a: undefined})).toBe(false);
    expect(utils.isEmpty({a: 5})).toBe(false);
    expect(utils.isEmpty({a: 5, b: 6, c: undefined})).toBe(false);
    expect(utils.isEmpty('f00')).toBe(false);
    expect(utils.isEmpty('0')).toBe(false);
  });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var message_1 = message.trim();     
if (message_1.length > 0) { 
    // to do
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.