# Check if a field of type string/number is empty

Tags: javascript

I am working with [editable grid](http://www.editablegrid.net/en) in my application. I have columns which vary from a string datatype to number, I am facing some problem While validating for emptiness of a grid cells. As easy as it sounds, it is getting confusing and frustrating.

This is what I am using to check if the field is empty:

```
if (value == "") {
//do work here
}
```

This works fine for columns with `string` datatype, but when a value of datatype `number` is there, it fails to check it as value contains `NaN` at that moment. I have tried most methods mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597900/checking-something-isempty-in-javascript), but in vain. Secondly, I also want to avoid nested or unnecessary ifs in this case..

Comment: You could check `if (value) {`.

Comment: for number use `parseInt` and then use `isNaN` method

Comment: Or check with typeof()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a check for a [falsy value](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)s by just 
checking for

```
if (!value) {
    //do work here
}
```

Which would evaluate to `true` for `0`,`""`,`null`,`undefined`,`false` and `NaN`

or of course if you want to test if the field is *not* empty you can just check for a `truthy` value

```
if (value) {
    //do work here
}
```

Which evaluates to `true` if the value is *not* `falsy` *(none of the above)*

Comment: Yes! It works now, though `if (value){...}` worked for me..thanks

Comment: You're welcome.
Oh, so you want to check for a `truthy` value (if the field is not empty), it's the same idea though, `if (value){...}` will evaluate to true if the value is none of the above mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can check for ***truthy*** value

```
if( value ) {
}
```

which evaluates to `true` is it is not from `('null', 'undefined', 'false', 'NaN' or 'empty' that is ("") )`