# jQuery isEmpty is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, input

Why this jQuery if statment is not working ?

```
if (isEmpty($('input.user'))) {
    alert ('123123');
}
```

This is reffering to input box with class of .user so basically if user left it empty alert.

Very basic but not working.

Comment: Please show us the code for `isEmpty`... it's not a built in function. It *might* be expecting the value of `input.user` rather than the jQuery object, so you could *try* `isEmpty($('input.user').val())`.

Comment: `$('input.user').val() === ""` or `$('input.user').val().length === 0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597900/checking-something-isempty-in-javascript

Comment: This is just a simple <input name=user type=text>

Comment: @blgt yes i know this method and it was working for me but i was looking for cleaner method that is why i asked

Comment: @puaction This method _is_ clean. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)</strike>

```
if ($('input.user').is(':empty')){
     alert ('I am Empty'); // alert ('123123');
}
```

---

```
if ($('input.user').val() === ''){ }
```

---

Or

```
if ($.trim($('input.user').val()) === ''){ }
```

---

Or

```
if ($.trim($('input.user').val()).length === 0){ }
```

Comment: `:empty` selects elements that have no children. It has nothing to do with the input's value.

Comment: Very Katcharra ;) hehe Varkala Trivandrum RULES !

Answer (score 6):

In jquery if you want to check if a form input is empty you can do it in this way:

```
if ( ! $('input.user').val()) {
    alert ('123123');
}
```

The method `.val()` will return `false` if the input element is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in JavaScript function for `isEmpty`.

If you want to check if a field is empty using jQuery you should use something like:

```
if (!$('input.user').val()){
   // DO SOMETHING
   alert ('123123');
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle that shows you how to check if a value is present on clicking a button - http://jsfiddle.net/jEte6/

To do the same using pure Javascript (No libraries)

If you're testing for an empty string:

```
if(myVar === ''){
    // Do something
}
```

If you're checking for a variable that has been declared, but not defined:

```
if(myVar === null){
    // Do something
}
```

If you're checking for a variable that may not be defined:

```
if(myVar === undefined){ 
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was including jQuery twice in my html. Check your html and if there are two, delete one and the problem should be fixed.