# Detecting if a Javascript variable is really undefined

Tags: javascript

How can we differentiate between `var foo;` and `var foo=undefined;`?

`typeof foo` will return for both "undefined" and `foo in window` will return for both true;

Comment: You don't--but why would you need to?

Comment: Unsure, but some of these posts might be of some help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null

Comment: `var foo;` is that `foo = undefined`. Therefore typeof foo returns "undefined"! I would ask: why do you need to do that? (or, what do you want to do?)

Comment: Worth mentioning here is [section `10.5` in the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5), where we have *" 8. For each VariableDeclaration and VariableDeclarationNoIn d in code, in source text order do ... Call env’s SetMutableBinding concrete method passing dn, undefined, and strict as the arguments."* So each variable is automatically initialized with `undefined`.

Comment: <strike>we can regex all the innerHTML of the script tag and see how foo was declared</strike>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`var foo` implies `var foo=undefined`, unless of course `undefined` is set to something other than `undefined`.

This can be seen in the Browser Console, if you initialise a variable but don't give it a value, it will have the value `undefined` (and the type `"undefined"`)

Comment: even if i change the value of `undefined`, all is the same. http://jsfiddle.net/UCjUK/

Comment: @user1365010: [Since ES5 you cannot change the value of `windwo.undefined` anymore](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.3). Of course you can create a local variable with name `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/gUamp/

Comment: @user1365010: You have to try harder than that (nowadays) to redefine `undefined` (which is a ***very, very, very bad idea***): http://jsfiddle.net/UCjUK/1/

Comment: It's not that bad, I must only put all my script in `(function(undefined){` and `})(3);`

Comment: Variable names should be a clear indication of what they are used for. There is no valid reason to name a variable "undefined".

Comment: @user1365010: It may not be very "hard", but it's certainly bad. Why would you want it?

Answer (score 2):

> How can we difference between `var foo;` and `var foo=undefined;`?

There **is** no difference between them, **if** this line precedes all uses of `foo`. (It doesn't have to.) The JavaScript engine sees the line `var foo=undefined;` like this:

```
// At top of scope
var foo; // `foo` will have the value `undefined`

// Where the var foo=undefined; line was
foo = undefined;
```

Note that they are completely different things that happen at different times. The declaration and the "initialization" (it's really an assignment) happen *separately*. The declaration happens upon entry to the execution unit; the initialization/assignment happens later, as part of the step-by-step code execution. (More: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html))

This means that if you have this:

```
foo = 5;
alert(typeof foo); // "number"
var foo = undefined;
alert(typeof foo); // "undefined"
```

...it is not an error, because the way the engine handles that is:

```
var foo;
foo = 5;
alert(typeof foo); // "number"
foo = undefined;
alert(typeof foo); // "undefined"
```

Answer (score 2):

A correct example works wonders:

```
function winFoo() {
  console.log('foo' in window);
}

function startFoo() {
  window.foo = 'bar';
}

function ovrFoo() {
  window.foo = undefined;
}

function removeFoo() {
  delete window.foo;
}

//window.foo === undefined
//window.foo hasn't been defined yet
winFoo(); //false
//so it makes sense that 'foo' is not in window
startFoo(); //window.foo === 'bar'
//window.foo has now been set to 'bar'
winFoo(); //true
//so it makes sense that 'foo' is in window
ovrFoo(); //window.foo === undefined
//window.foo has been overridden with a value of undefined
winFoo(); //true
//but the key 'foo' still exists in window, it just has a value of undefined
removeFoo(); //window.foo === undefined
//the key 'foo' has been removed from window and its value is therefor forgotten
winFoo(); //false
//so it makes sense that 'foo' is not in window
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KChna/)

Additionally, declaring `var foo` outside of any function context instantiates `window.foo` with a value of `undefined` if `!('foo' in window)` (meaning that if you call `var foo` multiple times in the same code block it doesn't override the existing value if there is one). More importantly, `var` and `function` statements are actually hoisted to the top of their scope, which means that:

```
console.log('foo' in window);
var foo;
console.log('foo' in window);
```

will print `true` twice instead of `false` followed by `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

```
if (null === var)
```

(to old browsers):

```
if (void 0 != var)
```

another one:

```
if(var)
```

and use it like:

```
var un;
if (un==undefined)
{
alert('Yes');
} else {
alert('No');
}
```

Comment: Note that `null` is not the same as `void 0`, moreover `var` is a keyword.