# How to check if a variable is both null and /or undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)
>   [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)
>   [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

In my code, I have a condition that looks like

```
if (variable !== null && variable !== undefined) {
}
```

But instead of doing it in two steps, i.e checking if it is not defined and not null. Is there a one step checking that replaces this check.

Comment: It's not exactly slowing down your code, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Use a function: `function isNullOrUndefined(variable) { return variable === null || variable === undefined; }`.

Comment: @VisioN If you pass an undefined variable to a function as an argument, you will get an error.

Comment: @dqhendricks that's not true, I don't think, though of course it may cause an error *inside* the function.

Comment: @VisioN you can certainly write a function but the `!=` operator handles this case already.

Comment: @Pointy Well yes. Just that insane idea...

Comment: @Pointy it most certainly is true. Run this and see what pops up in your log... http://jsfiddle.net/8JfbT/

Comment: @dqhendricks But it won't be an error if you set `baz` as `undefined`. Hence, it works only if the code is correct a priori.

Comment: @dqhendricks ah well there's a difference between an "undefined variable" and a "variable with the **value** `undefined`" ... [here's a modified version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/8JfbT/1/)

Comment: Yes, @Pointy My point is still valid however. If you want to test whether a variable has been defined, you cannot use a function.

Comment: @dqhendricks—any attempt to read an undeclared or un–initialsed variable will throw an error (except for `typeof`), including in the OP.

Comment: @RobG yep. `if (typeof foo === 'undefined') {`

Comment: the best way to do this is 

    if (!!!variable) { 
    //do something
    }

Comment: @msroot that test will also succeed if the value of the variable is `0`, `NaN`, the empty string, or `false`.

Comment: if (variable) {
      // your content here
    } will do the magic. In Js both `null` and `undefined` returns `false` inside if condition.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A variable cannot be both `null` and `undefined` at the same time.  However, the direct answer to your question is:

```
if (variable != null)
```

One `=`, not two.

There are two special clauses in the "abstract equality comparison algorithm" in the JavaScript spec devoted to the case of one operand being `null` and the other being `undefined`, and the result is `true` for `==` and `false` for `!=`.  Thus if the value of the variable is `undefined`, it's not `!= null`, and if it's not null, it's obviously not `!= null`.

Now, the case of an identifier *not being defined at all*, either as a `var` or `let`, as a function parameter, or as a property of the global context is different. A reference to such an identifier is treated as an error at runtime. You could attempt a reference and catch the error:

```
var isDefined = false;
try {
  (variable);
  isDefined = true;
}
catch (x) {}
```

I would personally consider that a questionable practice however. For global symbols that may or may not be there based on the presence or absence of some other library, or some similar situation, you can test for a `window` property (in browser JavaScript):

```
var isJqueryAvailable = window.jQuery != null;
```

or

```
var isJqueryAvailable = "jQuery" in window;
```

Comment: While this is correct and answers the OP's question, I think the original code is clearer. Not everyone will recognise the subtle difference between `x != null` and say `!x`.

Comment: @RobG well, I generally don't give "everyone" access to my source code repository :-)  I think it's kind-of important for JavaScript coders to know things like this, in other words.

Comment: Brilliant answer and it should have been accepted as the best.

Comment: it's not working for undefined variable

Comment: @ParthChavda what exactly do you mean? What's not working? In what way?

Comment: @Pointy when variable undefined

Comment: @ParthChavda As noted in the comments to the original question, testing for a variable simply not existing at all is not the intention of this code. That situation - the use of a non-defined variable - is simply an error, and is flagged as such in "strict" mode.

Comment: @Pointy thank you,i got it.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap it in your own function:

```
function isNullAndUndef(variable) {

    return (variable !== null && variable !== undefined);
}
```

Comment: Or atleast `return (variable !== null && variable !== undefined);` Come on! Thats like saying `if(true) { return true; } return false;`