# Showing a DIV only the first time a website is loaded with localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

I am trying to make this work but I have some problems.. Like the title says, I want a DIV to be showed only the first time a website is loaded. I know how to do with PHP and Cookies, but I want it with the localStorage function.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="loading_bg">
  ...
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
    if (localStorage.wasVisidet !== undefined ) {
            $("#loading_bg").css('display','none');
        } else {
            $("#loading_bg").delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
        }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use double equal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271750/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-both-null-and-or-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are setting the localStorage flag before the if condition, so the flag `wasVisited` will never be undefined.

You need to set the flag inside the else block as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') !== undefined) {
        $("#loading_bg").hide();
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
        $("#loading_bg").delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```