# How can I check a value for null in jquery without getting an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code:

```
if (returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom != null) {
```

...which throws this error (as seen in the Chrome Dev Tools console) when the value is, indeed, null:

```
Index:1031 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TimeUnitsFrom' of null
```

So how can I check for null in a way that I can avoid the error?

Based on a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271750/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-both-null-and-or-undefined-in-javascript), I even tried this:

```
if (returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom != null && variable !== undefined) {
```

...but I still get the same whinging from the guts of the browser.

Code in greater context:

```
function populatedaterangeprams(rptval, returneddata) {
    var fromval = '';
    var toval = '';
    if (returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom != null && returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom !== undefined) {
        fromval = returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom;
    }
    if (returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsTo != null && returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsTo !== undefined) {
        toval = returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsTo;
    }

    if (rptval === 1) {
        // Produce Usage
        $("#produsagefrom").val(fromval);
        $("#produsageto").val(toval);
    } else if (rptval === 2) {
    . . .
```

So how can I safely check for null in javascript/jQuery?

### UPDATE

As Phil Varg said, I needed to do this:

```
if (returneddata != null && returneddata.daterangeparams != null && returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom != null) {
    fromval = returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom;
}
if (returneddata != null &&
        returneddata.daterangeparams != null &&
        returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsTo != null) {
    toval = returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsTo;
}
```

...but that seems clunkier than a silicone-and-duct-tape job on the LHC. Isn't there a way to concisify this, where checking returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsTo for null would first check the first two subparticles of that?

Comment: You're trying to access a property that doesn't exist, you have to check each property as well.

Comment: Looks to me like daterangeparams might be null

Comment: Am I not checking with this: 
if (returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom != null && returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom !== undefined)
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `returneddata.daterangeparams` is null. and youre calling `TimeUnitsFrom` on it.
so you need to check that `returndata` is not null, and `returndata.daterangeparams` is not null, and `returneddata.daterangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom` is not null