# How do I check if an element is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I would like to check to see if a particular attribute of a DOM element is undefined - how do I do that?

I tried something like this:

```
if (marcamillion == undefined) {
    console.log("Marcamillion is an undefined variable.");
}
ReferenceError: marcamillion is not defined
```

As you can see, the reference error is telling me that the variable is not defined, but my `if` check is clearly not working, because it is producing the standard js `ReferenceError` as opposed to the error message I am looking for in my `console.log`.

**Edit 1**

Or better yet, if I am trying to determine if the attribute of an element is undefined like this:

`$(this).attr('value')`

What would be the best way to determine if that is undefined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `typeof`:

```
if (typeof marcamillion == 'undefined') {
    console.log("Marcamillion is an undefined variable.");
}
```

Edit for the second question:

```
if ($(this).attr('value')) {
    // code
}
else {
    console.log('nope.')
}
```

Comment: Say I have an attribute that I am trying to test the value of - i.e. `$(this).attr('value')`...what would be the best way to determine if that is undefined?

Comment: Simply doing `if ($(this).attr('value'))` will work.

Comment: How do I detect the `not` version of that? In ruby, I would just add a `!` infront of the condition, but I am getting an error now....or is that not possible here?

Comment: `if (!$(this).attr('value'))` should work. What error do you get?

Comment: Strange...I got an error before. Not quite sure why...but thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
if (typeof marcamillion === 'undefined') {
    console.log("Marcamillion is an undefined variable.");
}
```

Note that using `===` instead of `==` is considered better style.

Comment: Say I have an attribute that I am trying to test the value of - i.e. `$(this).attr('value')`...what would be the best way to determine if that is undefined?