# Why does Visual Studio warn me for 'null' in nullity-checked Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I really don't get why Visual Studio gives me the warning "Qualifier can be 'null' or 'undefined'" on the execution of "ra.split('')" below, even after I did a nullity check.
I have this code:

```
var ra = data.RiskAnalysis;
if (typeof ra !== "undefined") {
    var ebwg = ra.split('');
}
```

As you can read in [this stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2647888/1091947) 'typeof ra' would return 'object' if the value was null.

Is this a bug? Or isn't my check sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, that was a stupid question.
Ofcourse is the warning correct: If ra is equal to 'null' the if statement allows to go further because 'object' isn't equal to 'undefined'. Changed code to this:

```
if (typeof ra !== "undefined" && ra != null)
```