# How can I check whether an optional parameter was provided?

Tags: typescript

Given a function with optional parameters:

```
function DoSomething(a, b?) {
    /** Implementation */
}
```

How can I determine whether an optional parameter was provided from within the function body? Currently, the best way to do this that I can think of is:

```
typeof b === 'undefined'
```

But this is kind of messy and not straight-forward to read. Since TypeScript provides optional parameter support, I'm hoping it also has an intuitive way to check if a parameter was provided.

As the above example shows, I don't mind whether the optional parameter was explicitly set to `undefined` or not supplied at all.

#### Edit

Unfortunately, this question wasn't as clear as it should have been, particularly if it's skim-read. It was meant to be about how to *cleanly* check if an optional parameter is *completely omitted*, as in:

`DoSomething("some value");`

I've accepted Evan's answer since his solution (`b === undefined`) is cleaner than the one in my question (`typeof b === 'undefined'`) while still having the same behaviour.

The other answers are definitely useful, and which answer is correct for you depends on your use case.

Comment: Depends on what you want to check, someone could have called your method `foo(1, undefined)`. You could check `arguments.length`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, thanks; I think you're right. I've updated the question to clarify that either possibility is acceptable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear since it has run its course and ended up having multiple "correct" answers depending on how it's interpreted.

Comment: I don't understand why no one suggests using `??`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just check the value to see if it's undefined:

```
var fn = function(a) {
    console.log(a === undefined);
};
    
fn();          // true
fn(undefined); // true
fn(null);      // false
fn('foo');     // false
```

Comment: Yes, that generally seems to work in the same way that my example solution does. However, since this is a general question, I think it's safer to use the `typeof` check instead.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "general" question. Typically the only time you want to use `typeof` is if the variable isn't defined. eg `typeof somevar === 'undefined'`.

Comment: By "general question", I mean this question is not really providing any context, so I think it's best that the answer is also appropriate for all contexts.

Comment: The reason I believe the `typeof` check is safer is `undefined` can be redefined (either intentionally or accidentally) in some browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, my original question has been interpreted a couple of different ways. My intent was really about leaving an optional parameter absent, as in `fn(1)` in this answer.

In both TypeScript and JavaScript, the value is `undefined`, so Evan's answer here is closest to the mark and also shows that he read the intent behind the question. So I'm marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: I recently updated EvanTrimboli 's answer, and removed the first parameter, so for anyone reading Sam's last comment: `fn(1)` points to the first function call, now `fn()`.

Answer (score 50):

After googling "typescript check for undefined", I saw this question at the top of the results, but the answer given by Evan Trimboli did not solve my problem.

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273362/29613) that ultimately solved my problem. The following code is what I settled on. It should work in cases where the value equals `null` or `undefined`:

```
function DoSomething(a, b?) {
    if (b == null) doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I wonder about this. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#null-and-undefined says "don't use null". https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/null.html says "Null is bad". I'd be interested to find out more about the potential pitfalls of using `null` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: It says "NOTE: These are Coding Guidelines for TypeScript Contributors."

Comment: If you want to check if it has been set is it safe to check `if (b != null) doSomethingWith(b);`?

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are different values. In this example `DoSomething('smth', null)` we DO provide optional argument and `doSomething()` will be executed. If optional argument is not passed, then it will be `undefined`.

Comment: @TheJKFever yes `if (b != null) ...` does work as well.

Comment: Note: this works because (undefined == null) is true

Answer (score 11):

TypeScript's `util` module has function `isUndefined()`. You can use it like this.

```
import {isUndefined} from "util";

class A {
    test(b?: string): string {
        if (isUndefined(b)) {
            return "UNDEFINED";
        } else {
            return ("DEFINED" + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isUndefined` util function has been deprecated since v4. Use `value === undefined` instead.

Comment: You are right. The reason they (util.is* functions) were deprecated is because there were some issues, and fixing them will result in a lot of broken code. They decided to deprecate. I just created my own utils module and defined these functions.

Comment: As a side note: isUndefined is deprecated since v4.0.0 according to index.d.ts

Answer (score 8):

you could simple add an optional parameter with an default value like this

```
function DoSomething(a, b: boolean=null) {
    if(b == null)
    {
      //parameter was not set
    }
    else
    {
    //parameter is true or false...no other option available
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://dotnetpattern.com/typescript-optional-parameters) works without problems:

```
function getSchool(name: string, address?: string, pinCode?: string): string {
    if (typeof address === 'undefined') {
        console.log('address not defined');
    }
    if (typeof pinCode === 'undefined') {
        console.log('pincode not defined');
    }
    //...
}
```