# How to set a variable passed on to a function as null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function in JavaScript:

```
function something (variable) {
    console.log(variable);
}
```

How do I set that if there is no variable passed, then it is null by default?

Comment: Well if it's not passed its value will be undefined. Do you need specifically a `null` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript isn't very picky when it comes to the number of required function arguments when you call a function; any arguments that are mentioned in the declaration but not passed will be set to the type `undefined`.

For example:

```
function test(foo)
{
    console.log(foo === undefined); // true
}
```

To set default values there are at least three options:

```
function test(foo)
{
    console.log(foo || 'default value');
}
```

*The above will output the value of `foo` if it's truthy, or `'default value'` otherwise.*

```
function test(foo)
{
    console.log(foo === undefined ? foo : 'default value');
}
```

*This will output the value of `foo` if it's not `undefined`, or `'default value'` otherwise.*

Lastly, you can count the number of arguments that were passed:

```
function test(foo)
{
    console.log(arguments.length > 0 ? foo : 'default value');
}
```

*This will output the value of `foo` (regardless of its type) if an argument was passed.*

#### Further considerations

Although `undefined` is [not writeable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) since ES5, not all browsers will be so vigilant to enforce this. There are two alternatives you could use if you're worried about this:

```
foo === void 0;
typeof foo === 'undefined'; // also works for undeclared variables
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the size of `arguments` variable,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

```
function something (variable) {
  if(arguments.length===0){console.log("variable is null");}
  else{
    console.log(variable);
  }
}
```

Also have a look here in order to check if the variable is null,

[How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: technically there is nothing wrong with this answer, but what happens when two params are passed, or three, or four...

Comment: @John it is possible to use `arguments` for an arbitrary number of parameters and decide based on the state and position in the `arguments` object, regardless of the name of the variables. can you please elaborate a little more on your thought? maybe i'm missing something you are saying.

Comment: @John For example `arguments[0]` would correspond to `variable1`, `arguments[1]` would correspond to `variable2`, `argument[N-1]` would correspond to `variableN` in order to check their if `null` or something else. Also `argument.length===N-1` would mean that `variableN` has not been passed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fJp3/  I didn't realise you could use the arguments in this way.. i thought the arguments had to essentially be a numeric array.

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as:

```
function something (variable) {
    console.log(variable || null);
}
```

In general you can assign default values to parameters like this:

```
function something (somevar1, somevar2 /* ... somevarn */) {
    somevar1 = somevar1 || 'somevar1 not present';
    somevar1 = somevar2 || 2;
    somevar3 = somevar3 || {foo: 'bar', foobar: null}
    /* etc. */
}
```

Or, if you need a defence against `0`, `false`, etc. (and to serve [@Ketola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991314/ketola)), you could cook up something like:

```
function something (somevar1) {
    somevar1 = ['', 0, false, null, undefined].indexOf(somevar1) > -1
               && null || somevar1;
}
```

`... this || that` is known as [**short circuit evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: This only works for variables that evaluate to "true". `something(0,false)` would not work as expected.

Comment: OP asked 'How to set that *if there is no variable passed* ...'

Comment: True. But still that would not work. If "false" or 0 is passed, then `variable || null` evaluates to null.

Comment: If `false` or `0` is passed, *something*  is passed, albeit something evaluating to null.

Comment: OP asked "How to set that if there is no variable passed, then it is `null` by default", so the solution should not set the variable to `null` if variable *is* defined.

Answer (score 2):

All the above will work for sure, but this is the simplest approach and I use this the most.

```
variable = variable ? variable : undefined; // you can use null as well
```

Comment: This isn't functionally equivalent, though. `typeof x === 'undefined'` is much more specific, as this only checks for falsiness; `0`, `''` [and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true) are also falsey.

Answer (score 1):

Test the value of your variable like this:

```
function something (variable) {
    variable = (typeof variable !== 'undefined') ? variable : null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice I wasn't editing my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or a more friendly (IMO) option would be:

```
function getProfile( singleVariable )
{
    singleVariable = singleVariable || false;
    if (singleVariable) {
        alert('we have a var')
    }
    else {
        alert('nothing opassed');
    }
}
getProfile();
getProfile('tom');
```

Then when you start passing lots of parameters over, but want the function to be flexible you can do:

```
function getProfile(params)
{
    params = params || {};

    if (params.username) {
        alert(params.username)
    }
    if (params.id) {
      alert(params.id);
    }
}
getProfile();
getProfile({username:'tom', id: 123654987});
```

Instead of

```
function getProfile(singleVariable, otherVar, othervar2)
{
    singleVariable = singleVariable || false;
    otherVar = otherVar|| false;
    otherVar2 = singleVariable2 || false;

    if( singleVariable ){
        alert('we have a var')
    }
    else {
        alert('nothing opassed');
    }
}

getProfile('tom', false, 'smith');
```

That false is required and is annoying.. passing an abject is far more efficient

Comment: Thanks, @John - and if I pass something like getProfile('tom', 'smith) – then the function assumes that othervar2 is null? or false? or undefined?

Comment: undefined. however i really strongly advise against using this method. as your application grows the management of parameters passed in this fashion becomes a nightmare.

Comment: in fact any 3rd party pluggin that is half decent will expect an array (object) passed to it. eg: $.ajax({url:'www.blah',type:'GET',success:function(data){alert(data);}})   To add to this, as you are passing effectively an assoc array, the order of the params you pass them in is irrelevant

Comment: This solution will raise false-negatives if `singleVariable` is a falsy value, but a value you passed on purpose nonetheless.

Comment: The `|| false` doesn't affect the behavior of the program; the function would work the same if that line was removed.