# check JavaScript variable null or not?

Tags: javascript, html, null, var

Iam using following lines of code to check whether the JS variable 'userName' is null or not.
But am always getting `alert "not empty"`

Please check my `onready` method:

```
$("document").ready(function (){
    var userName = "";
    if (userName == undefined || userName == null) {
        alert('empty');
    } else {
        alert('not empty');
        var div = document.getElementById('title b');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ','; 
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe this is what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `typeof` keyword to check it's type. `!userName` will take care of the rest, like null or empty values.

```
if ( typeof userName === 'undefined' || !userName ) {
    alert('empty');
}
```

Comment: No need to use `===` here, because the return of `typeof` is always a string and `==` is faster in this case ;)

Comment: @Beterraba: some js linters tend to yell if non-strict equalities are used. So it's a habit for me. But in general you're right :)

Comment: Actually, can you explain the point of type check, since `!undefined` is true anyways?

Comment: I put it there to correct the original code chunk. Logically it has no use since `userName` gets initialized as an empty string, thus not undefined. But we never know what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `var userName` to `""`. It will *never* be `null`.

Declare your variable as `var userName;`, instead of `var userName = "";`

However, unless you actually do something with `userName`, the `if / else` will be pretty pointless.

Comment: so the null in json is equal to  'var userName'   instead of 'var userName="" '???

Comment: A value of `null` in a JSON string will be parsed as `null`, not as an empty string, indeed.

Comment: so how do i detect 'null ' here  (!userName)??

Comment: Simple: `if(userName == null)`

Answer (score 1):

Empty string is not null nor undefined.

You can check using the `!` operator:

```
if (!userName) {
   // Do the stuff
}
```

For completeness:

```
!"" == true
!null == true
!undefined == true
!"hi" == false
```

Note that:

```
!0 == true
!1 == false
!"0" == false
!"1" == false
```

Comment: If `userName` happens to be `0`, `!userName` will be `true`; `!1` -> `false`. Don't just cast the username to a boolean like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus As the var tend to be a string, I do not see the problem of this being a number 0. But yes, I'll expose this on the answer. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

No your variable is neither undefined nor null.

What you could do though is this replace this line

```
if (userName == undefined || userName == null) {
```

by this line

```
if (!userName) {
```

Comment: If `username === 0`, that check will pass.

Comment: If the input is read from an html element, it will always be a string, right ?

Comment: Yes, but that is assuming it's actually read from a input element.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var userName = "";
    if (userName.length < 1) {
        alert('empty' +"\n"+ userName.length);
    } else {
        alert('not empty');
        var div = document.getElementById('title b');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ','; 
    }
```