# TypeError 'undefined' occurs sometimes during Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here my ajax request and response,I have around 85 HTML pages with same ajax request.When i work with these files sometimes im getting following error

[image]

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('currentPageNo', 9);
    ResetSwiper();
    CheckPageReadCompleted();
    extrapopuptrigger("1");
});


function ResetSwiper() {
    toggle_text = localStorage.getItem("currentBibleVersion");
    myView = $(".scrollpane").data("mobileIscrollview");
    if(toggle_text == "ESV") {
        $(".searchContent").hide();
        $(".esvContent").show();
        setTimeout(function() {
        var text_search = null;
        $(".esvContent").html('Loading...');
        text_search = $(".searchTitle").html();
        xhr = $.ajax({                      
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/verse?key=IP&passage="+text_search+"&include-footnotes=false",
            data:"",
            contentType: "text/html",
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(resp) {
                $(".esvContent").html(resp);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(myView != null || myView != 'undefined') {
                        myView.refresh();
                    }
                },100);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
            if(is_uiwebview) {
                  natviveAlert("StandFIRM","Unable to connect internet.Please try again!");
            } else {
                window.JSInterface.showAlertDialog("StandFIRM","Unable to connect internet.Please try again!");
            }
            }
        },100);
    });
    } else{
        $(".esvContent").hide();
        $(".searchContent").show();
        myView.refresh();
    }
 }
```

How can i solve this issue?Can any one please help me to solve

Comment: can you demonstrate it in a fiddle

Comment: Which is the line that the error occurs on?

Comment: @ExplosionPills error at `myView.refresh();`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad   http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AT3yuaV4qR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` should not have quotes

```
   if(myView != undefined) {
     myView.refresh();
    }
```

**Edit:**

As @filoxo suggested you can use quotes for `undefined` but you should add `typeof` before comparison.

```
   if(typeof myView != 'undefined') {
     myView.refresh();
    }
```

Check this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: I might also be nice to note that it *would be* in quotes if using `typeof` ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)), and you could also check for a variable value by simply doing `if( myView ){ ... }`.

Comment: i changed ,its shows error now with else part myView.refresh();

Comment: @Fazil just only this condition `if(myView != undefined)` in `setTimeout()`

Comment: @MRSrinivas i have changed `if(myView != undefined)` in `setTimeout()`.But now error showing with `else` part `myView.refresh();`

Comment: by adding `if(typeof myView != 'undefined') {   myView.refresh();    }` this in else condition resolve the issue thankx