# 'Undefined' or 'Null' Variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, null, undefined

While trying to learn JavaScript I came across a few snippets of code that has confused me.

My original code that I was messing around with was:

```
var username = prompt("Choose a username:");

if (username === null) {
    alert("Username is required!");
} else {
    console.log("Your username is: " + username);
}
```

This **didn't** work. So I came here and found this question: [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null). Even though I found my solution it raised more questions that I couldn't find the answer for within the sea of "answers".

The first solution that has 910 upvotes uses `typeof`, but this **didn't** work for me:

```
var username = prompt("Choose a username:");

if (typeof username === 'undefined'){
    alert("Username is required!");
} else {
    console.log("Your username is: " + username);
}
```

It also states a shorter version, which **did** work for me:

```
var username = prompt("Choose a username:");

if (!username){
    alert("Username is required!");
} else {
    console.log("Your username is: " + username);
}
```

Another answer caught my eye as it included a part of my personal code `username === null`, which has 319 upvotes, but this **didn't** work for me either:

```
var username = prompt("Choose a username:");

if (username === undefined || username === null) {
    alert("Username is required!");
} else {
    console.log("Your username is: " + username);
}
```

An edit to the answer also states that using just `username === null` is sufficient.

So my **question** is why does `!username` work with that specific code but the others did not?

Comment: Your first code works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/59zutyLd/

Comment: First one doesn't work at all. Nothing gets alerted, because username does not equal null. It equals an empty string.

Comment: @nevermind Your jsfiddle still only logs `Your username is: ` when no value is entered (on chrome 45).

Comment: @X.L.Ant, i see null logged, and see alert? firefox and chrome?!

Comment: @X.L.Ant, huh, forget it - it works as intended on 'cancel' lol - misunderstanding....

Comment: Turn on your debugger and examine the value of `username`.

Comment: You were looking for the wrong question, [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) always return a string. So there's no point in checking if it's `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not too sure this deserves downvotes since I'm exceptionally new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are prompted for a username and don't type in anything, the value stored is an empty string, `''`. This equals the value `false` in JavaScript.

The reason why the `typeof(username) == undefined` one didn't work is because the username variable was declared in the previous line. As I mentioned above, the type of username is a string, even if nothing was typed in.

And yes, to check if a variable is undefined, use `typeof varName === undefined`.

Comment: So would this be the same reasoning for `null`?

Comment: I already explained the value for `username` is `''`, an empty string. That means it has a value and is defined. So it's neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Comment: so you would simply use `if (!username)`? Or is there something else you would use?

Comment: It is incorrect to say that an empty string is equal to `false`.

Comment: Yes it is, try it for yourself. `'' == false` will return true

Answer (score 0):

in javaScript if a `variable` is `undefined` then that means it is `!= null`.
if one variable is `null` and second is `undefined` than result for `==` will be `true` and for `!=` will be `false`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
typeof username === 'undefined'
```

Instead of:

`username === undefined`

if you try:

```
typeof username === undefined
```

Will fail too.

Javascript :-)

Comment: That won't work. `typeof` always returns a string. The second one isn't valid syntax

Comment: Providing a list of things that also fail does not provide an answer to the question.