# how to solve undefined variable: mime_boundary

Tags: php

This my code plz provide me solution

```
<?php
    class email
    {
      function emailWithAttach($fromaddress,$toAddress,$mailSubject,$mailMessageHead,$mailMessageMain,$mailMessageSign,$filePath,$fileName)
     {
     $fileatt_name = $fileName;
     $fileatt = $filePath.$fileName;
     $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream";
     $email_from = $fromaddress;
     $email_subject = $mailSubject;
     $email_message = $mailMessageHead."<br>";
     $email_message .= $mailMessageMain."<br>";
     $email_message .= $mailMessageSign;
     $headers = '';
     $email_to = $toAddress;
     $headers = "From: ".$email_from;
     $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
     $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
     fclose($file);
     empty($mime_boundary); /*i also tried empty function still getting notice.*/
     $semi_rand = md5(time());
     $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_X{$semi_rand}X";

     $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

      $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
      $email_message .= "\n\n";

      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

      $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
      " name=\" {$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
      $data .= "\n\n". /*i m getting error on this line */
      "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";


      if(@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
      {
          return true;
      }
      }
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: Where do you set the $mime_boundary variable? It looks like you a referring to a non defined variable.

Comment: Give us the complete error message including line number!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I strongly recommend that you have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works. SO is **not** a free debug service.

Comment: @deceze  complete error message Notice: Undefined variable: mime_bondary in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\talentpunditsv2\current-openings\jobs\emailClass.php on line 41

Comment: ***bondary***?! Really? If really so, you merely have a ***typo***.

Comment: @deceze might be but i m unable to find that typo. could you plz help me to find out that typo

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
$mime_boundary = isset($mime_boundary) ? $mime_boundary : '';
```

in place of:

```
empty($mime_boundary);
```

but i think this is no sense...this variable ($mime_boundary) is not exist in your function, so this is empty. You can skip this check and remove this line.

Comment: i also tried without empty($mime_boundary) but still i m facing same issue