# Checking for null or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Although there are semantic differences between JavaScript's `null` and `undefined`, many times they can be treated as the same. What's the preferable way of checking if the value is either null or undefined?

---

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null) {
    // do something
}
```

Which is pretty verbose. I could, of course, create a function for this and import everywhere, but I'm wishing that there's a better way to achieve this.

<s>Also, I know that</s>

```
if (value == null) {
}
```

Will get the job done 90% of the time, unless value is zero... or false... or a number of implicit things that can cause obscure bugs.

Comment: if you want to test for specific values, you need verbosity ... although, you can shorten it a bit, `if (value === undefined || value === null) {`

Comment: You often don't need to do defensive null checks at all. But I can't answer your question more without seeing more of your code. Zoom out and show us the bigger picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: I think the commonly used one is  the  ``typeof a === "undefined"`` way

Comment: @hamism: Um, except that will be false for `null`.

Comment: TJ was right -- I ended up confusing comparison this with falsiness. I strikedout the part of the question that affirmed a very silly thing. Oh, @AngelPolitis, I didn't find that question. Indeed, it's a duplicate.

Comment: Yes @T.J.Crowder you're right.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Also, I know that
>
> ```
> if (value == null) {
> }
> ```
>
> Will get the job done 90% of the time, unless value is zero... or false... or a number of implicit things that can cause obscure bugs.

No, it gets the job done 100% of the time. The only values that are `== null` are `null` and `undefined.` `0 == null` is false. `"" == undefined` is false. `false == null` is false. Etc. You're confusing `== null` with falsiness, which is a very different thing.

That's not to say, though, that it's a good idea to write code expecting everyone to know that. You have a perfectly good, clear check in the code you're already using. Whether you choose to write `value == null` or the explicit one you're currently using (or `if (value === undefined || value === null)`) is a matter of style and in-house convention. But `value == null` does do what you've asked: Checks that `value` is `null` or `undefined`.

The details of `==` are here: [*Abstract Equality Comparison*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: Thanks TJ, I was actually confusing things.

Comment: Although this is correct javascript a lint checker such as jslint or eslint may still complain about it, though most will have some sort of configuration setting to allow == for testing against null e.g. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/910

Answer (score 0):

underscore js has a function for this `_.isUndefined()`

from https://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined

> **isUndefined**     _.isUndefined(value)
>   Returns true if value is undefined.
>
> example:
>   _.isUndefined(window.missingVariable);
>   => true

lodash has a similar function. see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isUndefined

Both have similar functions for `isNull` too.

I find the functions are useful for others to know what is being tested for.