# How check property without hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

I have object like this `var o = $scope['reservation']['bookings'][bookingKey]['meals']`

When I do

```
if (o.hasOwnProperty('checkedProperty') {

  // code

}
```

I have error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`.

I try too:

```
if (o['checkedProperty']) {

  // code to do if my object 'o' has 'checkedProperty'

}
```

but I have error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '26' of undefined`.

How can I do to check this property?

Comment: `o` is `undefined`

Comment: check if the object is `undefined` first, then proceed.

Comment: `try/catch` if you don't want to work hard. or `if (o != null && o.reservations != null && o.reservations.bookings != null...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Answer (score 2):

You can't check if a property exists on an object when you don't have an object in the first place.

Check if `o` actually is an object:

```
if (typeof o !== "undefined" && o.hasOwnProperty('checkedProperty')) {
```

Comment: This will also fail if `o` is `null`. As a general solution: `if (o != null && o.hasOwnProperty('checkedProperty')) {` This assumes `o` has been declared. Otherwise: `if (typeof o !== 'undefined' && o !== null && o.hasOwnProperty('checkedProperty')) {`