# Is there any way to distinguish between an unset property and a property set to undefined?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the object `testObject = {a: undefined}`. If I then `console.log(testObject.a)`, I get undefined. But the same happens if I `console.log(testObject.b)`, which doesn't exist. Is there any way in JavaScript to distinguish between `a` and `b` here? I ask mostly out of curiosity, I have no use case.

Comment: just found one possible answer-- use `Object.keys(testObject)`.

Comment: I think you are looking for `undefined` and `null`

Comment: No, I'm not. I don't know what would give you that impression. I'm not new to JavaScript.

Comment: Since you're not new to JavaScript you know https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined for sure. Which indeed leeds to the assumption you want to distinguish between `undefined` and `null`. If not, your question does not make much sense...

Comment: It's especially funny if you go to my profile and look at my highest voted answer.

Comment: @Aerovistae I don't see any point to start a fight here and also I'm surprised of you being so upset. At least for me your question was too vague and did not make much sense - what I wrote. I guess your question is answered in the duplicate then, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property.

In given case -

```
  testObject = {a: undefined};

  testObject.hasOwnProperty('a') // true
  testObject.hasOwnProperty('b') // false
```

Comment: Just a pointer. You should try to explain why changes you made would work. Just saying `Try this`, is not a good answer

Answer (score 3):

You can actually distinguish with extra condition before checking using `in` operator

```
if(a in testObject) {
  // it's there .. now check whether it is undefined or not
}
```

Comment: `in` will also pass for properties on prototype and will fail for non-enumerable properties

Answer (score 2):

```
testObject.hasOwnProperty('a')
```

Note that this will only work for objects like you show; inherited properties from prototype won't pass this test (which is the point of `hasOwnProperty`).