# JavaScript: Check if Object is null or undefined when getting property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanna do like this simply:

```
const someProp = someObj ? someObj.someProp : undefined;
```

In Ruby, we can use `&` operator.

```
some_prop = some_obj&.some_prop
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: [This article](https://www.beyondjava.net/elvis-operator-aka-safe-navigation-javascript-typescript) should be a good read for you to understand what your options are.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [*optional chaining operator*](https://github.com/TC39/proposal-optional-chaining) which is also currently a stage 1 proposal:

```
const someProp = someObj?.someProp;
```

However, for the time being you could write a helper function:

```
function opt(obj, prop) {
  return obj ? obj.prop : null;
}

const someProp = opt(someObj, 'someProp');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such operator currently in javascript.

There's a proposal for `??` to be added https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing, but it's only at stage 1 meaning it's far from being in the language yet.