# Angular 6 HttpClient set param date only if its not null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to pass parameter to URL. For which I am using Angular HttpParams. How do I set date param only if date is not null or undefined?

Code:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
   .set('Id', Id)
   .set('name', name)

if (startDate !== null) {
    params.set('startDate', startDate.toDateString());
}

if (endDate !== null) {
    params.set('endDate', endDate.toDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`set` does not mutate the object on which it is working - it returns a *new object* with the new value set. You can use something like this:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
   .set('Id', Id)
   .set('name', name)

if (startDate != null) {
    params = params.set('startDate', startDate.toDateString());
}

if (endDate != null) {
    params = params.set('endDate', endDate.toDateString());
}
```

Note how the `params` object is being *reassigned*. Also note the use of `!=` to protect against both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: You should avoid avoid != null   except for "boolean", generally you juste write  if(startDate) {       if(endDate) {

Comment: @xrobert35 Yes I knew this was a sensitive area - [This](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/null-undefined.html) says what I went with is good to use (so does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)).

Comment: @xrobert35 I have the param "page", so, `page=0` is a valid param for me, and `if (page)` will false, but wouldn't be...

Comment: please vote for the conditional HttpParams set update feature: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26021

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the HttpParams object you can define and mutate your own object and pass it within the http call.

```
let requestData = {
  Id: Id,
  name: name
}
if (startDate) {
//I am assuming you are using typescript and using dot notation will throw errors 
//unless you default the values
  requestData['startDate'] = startDate
}
if (endDate) {
  requestData['endDate'] = endDate
}

//Making the assumption this is a GET request
this.httpClientVariableDefinedInConstructor.get('someEndpointUrl', { params: requestData })
```

Comment: imagine instead of startDate is the `page` param... `page` set to `0` will fail your `set`...

Comment: more than that, requetData[page] == requestData[0]... not good ( probably `requestData['page']` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the correction with the missing quotes and in your case you can do if(page!==undefined && page!==null). At that point you can still assign the page property to the object.