# Delete null or undefined attributes in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, destructuring

I want to create a method to delete null and undefined attributes.

To do that :

> I convert my plain object into table
>
> loop on it
>
> filter on attributes if there are null or undefined

But the thing is I don't arrive to restructure my object with the new values. Let's take a look :

```js
var req = {
    adtForm1: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: undefined,
      middleName: ''
    },
    adtForm2: {
      firstName: null,
      lastName: 'Doe',
      middleName: ''
    }
  };

  removeUndefinedFormsAttributes = (somesForms) => {
    const forms = Object.values(somesForms);
    const formsUpdate = {};
    forms.forEach(item => {
      const formFields = Object.values(item);
      formFieldsKeys = Object.keys(item);
      const formFiltered = formFields.filter(field => { return field !== null && field !== undefined; });
      console.log("formFiltered", formFiltered);
    })
    console.log(somesForms)
    return forms;
  };

removeUndefinedFormsAttributes(req)
```

As we can see in the snippet, formFiltered change the good values but I need to return the same object as somesForms.
This is what I need :

```
expectedValue = {
    adtForm1: {
        firstName: 'John',
        middleName: ''
    },
    adtForm2: {
        lastName: 'Doe',
        middleName: ''
    }
}
```

I know I need to use reduce() function and keys() function but truly I don't know how. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to modify the original object, or do you want to create a new structure?

Comment: Modify the original one by deleting null attributes.

Comment: Your accepted answer is creating a new object structure, leaving the original untouched. Using `.reduce()` is the wrong tool if you're just mutating the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursively iterate the object and create a new object without `null` or `undefined`. Use `Object.entries()` to get the keys and value pairs from the object. Iterate the pairs with `Array.reduce`. Ff a value is `null` or `undefined` skip it's key. If it's an object assign the result of calling `removeUndefinedFormsAttributes` on the value to the key. And if it's not an object just assign the value to the key.

```js
const req = {"adtForm1":{"firstName":"John","middleName":""},"adtForm2":{"firstName":null,"lastName":"Doe","middleName":""}};

const removeUndefinedFormsAttributes = (obj) => 
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if(v === null || v === undefined) return r;
    if(typeof v === 'object') r[k] = removeUndefinedFormsAttributes(v);
    else r[k] = v;
    
    return r;
  }, {});

const result = removeUndefinedFormsAttributes(req)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm looking at how entries and reduce works to be able to reuse them. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to remove keys with `null` or `undefined` values from objects nested one level down, then you can iterate over the values of your main object using `Object.values`, then iterate over the keys of each nested object using `Object.keys`, and delete those that match your conditions. You can test the values of your nested objects to determine if they are `null` or `undefined` with something like `value == null` (see [How to determine if variable is undefined or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)).

If you need to remove keys at various nested levels in your object or in an object where some of the nested values are of different types, then check out some of the other answers that employ recursion and type checking.

For example:

```js
const req = { adtForm1: { firstName: 'John', lastName: undefined, middleName: '' }, adtForm2: { firstName: null, lastName: 'Doe', middleName: '' } };
Object.values(req).forEach((v) => {
  Object.keys(v).forEach((k) => {
    if (v[k] == null) {
      delete v[k];
    }
  });
});

console.log(req);
// {"adtForm1":{"firstName":"John","middleName":""},"adtForm2":{"lastName":"Doe","middleName":""}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you need to modify the actual object instead of creating a new structure. If so, then you don't want `.reduce()`. You just need a recursive function that modifies the given object.

```js
var req = {
  adtForm1: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: undefined,
    middleName: ''
  },
  adtForm2: {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: 'Doe',
    middleName: ''
  }
};

function removeUndefinedFormsAttributes(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (v == null) {
        delete obj[k];
      } else if (typeof v === "object") {
        removeUndefinedFormsAttributes(v);
      }
    })
};

removeUndefinedFormsAttributes(req);

console.log(req);
```

Here I used `Object.entries` to get the key/value pairs for the given object.

If `v` is `null` or `undefined`, it will `delete` that `k` from the object. If `v` is an object, it makes a recursive call with that object.

FYI, doing `v == null` is the same as doing `v === null || v === undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  let removeNotNeedet = ( obj ) => {
    let newObj = {} 
    for (const key in obj) {
        if ( obj[key] !== null && obj[key] !== undefined ){
            newObj[key] = obj[key]
        }
    }
    return newObj
  }
```

Comment: don't iterate with child values;

Answer (score 0):

You can simply clone those attributes into a new object if their aren't null or undefined.

Quite simple code that loops recursively through obj and only insert attributes if they are valid:

```
function clearObject(object) {
    if (typeof(object) != "object") return false;

    const clean_object = {};

    for (let k in object) {
        let item = object[k];
        if (item === null || item === undefined) continue;
        clean_object[k] = clearObject(item) || item;
    }

    return clean_object;
}
```