# After an check if something is not null I get a null or undefined type error. How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jagged-arrays

I have an fairly complex array of elements which is stored in the state of my redux store. This is not that important to the issue. I have an this snippet of code which break on occasion ( 1/30 evaluations ). I have tried to debug this problem for several days now. You can ignore the logic behind If statement this is not the issue. The issue is that the second part of the evaluation in the statement breaks. The ternary operator checks if something is not null then executes an separate check in which I get type error that the value I'm checking is null. How would this be possible?

I have tried console logging this issue in multiple ways every outcome is expected the value exists. I have tried reformatting the code expecting it could be browser related. It seems to be more persistent on Google Chrome browser then it is on Microsoft edge.

```
 const indexLeft = state.Board[index].Left;
if (
!state.InitialPlay &&
   (
       state.Board[index].RoadTopRight !== null ? state.Board[index].RoadTopRight.Type._ !== player.Type._ : true ||
       state.Board[index].RoadRight !== null ? state.Board[index].RoadRight.Type._ !== player.Type._ : true ||
       state.Board[indexRight].RoadTopLeft !== null ? state.Board[indexRight].RoadTopLeft.Type._ !== player.Type._ : true
   )
) return state;
```

Expected actual result would be that the value when the ternary operator evaluates would be different from null. This is the only check necessary since Road types only get declared players so it cannot have an scenario where road type would not have the property Type.

If you're interested in solving this mystery and you don't mind the total and utter mess and clutter of my code this is the github repository in question and the module in question: https://github.com/AnteVuletic/Internship-17-React4/blob/master/src/redux/modules/board.js

You can find the issue in the function literal called _setCrossroad

[image]

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: On a separate note, this condition is super hard to read...

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for your feedback. Yes the condition is horrible this is proof of concept code which I wasn't sure it would work. There is much refactoring to be done.

Comment: The error is: https://i.imgur.com/xBGZQfe.png

Comment: Well, the erros says that `RoadTopRight` or `RoadRight` or `RoadTopLeft` is `undefined` or `null`. You're only checking for `null`...

Comment: Perhaps `const ip  = state.InitialPlay;
const rtr = state.Board[index].RoadTopRight;
const rr  = state.Board[index].RoadRight;
const rtl = state.Board[indexRight].RoadTopLeft;
const pt  = player.Type._;
return  !ip &&
   (rtr && rtr !== pt ||
    rr  && rr  !== pt || 
    rtl && rtl !== pt) ?
 state : null;`

Comment: the other thing is, `player` could also be null. I don't see you check that case and you're also accessing its 'Type' property.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this suggestion @mplungjan . I will test this suggestion since the != ternary check did not solve the issue ( although it was useful since I learned something new :) )

Comment: @Thomas player is never null it is assigned much earlier then the if statement is ran. The problem occurs ( not always but in some scenario that I cannot resolve ) when the state.Board[index].[Property] evaluates to something other then null or undefined or player. Which shouldn't be the case the hexmodel as shown  at the comments below ( https://github.com/AnteVuletic/Internship-17-React4/blob/master/src/redux/models/hexModel.js ) sets the roads to null. During execution players get assigned to this roads with onClick events but there is an scenario where roads become something that passes...

Comment: ... != null evaluation but is not an object of type player. Which breaks into the error posted above.

Comment: @mplungjan `if(condition) return value` and `return condition? value: null;` are two different things. And you got the ternary conditions wrong. that's how that part should look like: `if(!state.InitialPlay && (!rtr || rtr.Type._ !== pt || !rr || rr.Type._ !== pt || !rtl || rtl.Type._ !== pt)) return state;` but for readability that's no better than the original code.

Comment: I assume the function will need to return SOMETHING if not state - the null can be changed or undefined can be returned

Comment: if nothing else, it will return `undefined`, but before we're there, there might be more code that doesn't fit very well if you squeeze it into a ternary condition. Loops would be the worst I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `state.Board[index].RoadTopRight`, `state.Board[index].RoadRight` and `state.Board[indexRight].RoadTopLeft` are **undefined**

your condition should be `!=` or `!{variable_name}`

```
const indexLeft = state.Board[index].Left;
if(!state.InitialPlay &&
   (
       state.Board[index].RoadTopRight != null ? state.Board[index].RoadTopRight.Type._ !== player.Type._ : true ||
       state.Board[index].RoadRight != null ? state.Board[index].RoadRight.Type._ !== player.Type._ : true ||
       state.Board[indexRight].RoadTopLeft != null ? state.Board[indexRight].RoadTopLeft.Type._ !== player.Type._ : true
   )
) return state;
```

because **undefined !== null** will always be true

Comment: This makes perfect sense. If you may elaborate a bit more.

Comment: This is the model in question https://github.com/AnteVuletic/Internship-17-React4/blob/master/src/redux/models/hexModel.js

Comment: @AnteVuletić https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null

Comment: You can see here that the roads are being initialized to null in the constructor. Could there be an case where they wouldn't be null?