# check if clipboard content is empty using @ionic-native/clipboard

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i want  to check if the clipboard content is empty so if it is, i show an alert to the user saying the clipboard is empty else i assign the clipboard content to the variable content

this is what i have tried but it doesn't show the alert

```
public pastetoinput(){
    this.clipboard.paste().then(
        (resolve: string) => {
            if(resolve == "" || resolve == null){
                 alert("clipboard is empty");
            }else{
                 var content = resolve
            }
        },
        (reject: string) => {
            console.error('Error: ' + reject);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you injected the Clipboard provider in your constructor? Maybe you should also check if the `resolve` variable would be `undefined` instead of `null`.

Code Example:

```
import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard/ngx';

constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard) { }

public pastetoinput(){
    this.clipboard.paste().then(
        (resolve: string) => {
            if(resolve === "" || resolve === null || resolve === undefined){
                 alert("clipboard is empty");
            }else{
                 var content = resolve
            }
        },
        (reject: string) => {
            console.error('Error: ' + reject);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: If you check `resolve == null` it will check for the `undefined` and `null` as well :) so no need to write `resolve === undefined`

Comment: @YashRami You are right, it works if you use the *abstract equality operator* instead of `===` (detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2647888/2764486)

Comment: Spark Fountain Yes Mate :)