# Test if variable is Null, Undefined, Blank, or Empty Object including Date items

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, javascript-objects

How do I check if a Variable (whether, number, string, date, Object, etc)

is null, blank, undefined or empty?

The following fails for any Date, with lodash isEmpty always returning NotEmpty for dates.

```
if (test == null || test == '' || _.isEmpty(test){
    console.log('variable is empty');
}
```

Anyway to do this is in a clean manner?  Reading the links below,

[How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

[How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: What defines an "empty" date? Indeed I think any date object should never return true for a condition like that.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be handling all these cases in a single check, rather figure out exactly what you need and check for its validity. For example, if you're checking for a valid date, use `lodash.isDate` rather than checking if it's `undefined`, `null`, `string`, `number`, or whatever.

Comment: The only condition I can think of for a date being empty would be `new Date(0)` ( 0 milliseconds from epoch). But that would never be a value you'd have to deal with in the _vast_ majority of cases.

Comment: well needed a clean answer to accomodate for dates also

Comment: @Klaycon  any date which is null blank, undefined, or empty

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 dates cannot be null or blank or undefined or empty. if a variable that's supposed to have a date in it has one of those values instead, it *is not* a date, and your current condition will catch this on the `test == null`. please be more specific and describe what exact value is giving you undesirable results

Comment: If you're strictly testing for a `Date` then you should use something like `date-fns.isValid`, then no matter what you pass (`null`, `undefined`, `blank`, **whatever**), it will give you the right result - https://date-fns.org/v2.10.0/docs/isValid. Simply create a `Date` object with value that you're given and do the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply testing for the variable's [falsiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) should cover all of these cases.

```
if (!test){
    console.log('variable is empty');
}
```

Note that, like your current condition, this condition will never be true for any `Date` object as there is no defined "falsy" state for `Date`s. If however a variable that should have a `Date` has `null` or `undefined` instead it will work.

Comment: If `false` "null, blank, undefined or empty"? I'd argue it's none of those. Though to be fair, the ask is somewhat unclear.

Comment: well needed a clean answer to accomodate for dates also

Comment: accepted answer and gave points, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks

Comment: Empty object `{}` is not a falsy value. The accepted answer isn't correct for all given cases above