# What is a concise way to check if a value is truthy or 0?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to simplify checking if an index value is `null` or `undefined` in typescript.

```
    const indexValue: number;
    if(!!indexValue || indexValue === 0) {
     // Do something
    }
```

Since `0` is falsy, it seems like it needs to be explicitly checked for in the condition with `indexValue === 0`.

If there a more clear and concise way to do this?

Comment: It's either that or `indexValue === undefined || indexValue === null`.

Comment: "is truthy or 0", "is null or undefined", which one?!

Comment: `indexValue != null`

Comment: What is `!!indexValue`? Why not `indexValue` ?

Comment: Note that `NaN` is falsy but is neither undefined nor null. You likely also want to reject `Infinity` and `-Infinity`. Consider instead `if (Number.isFinite(indexValue))`, which will reject non-numbers, null, undefined, NaN, and infinities. Perhaps clarify what you're going to use this number for, as the set of unacceptable values depends on that.

Comment: What's complex on `if (indexValue !== undefined && indexValue !== null) { ... }` o.O

Comment: If it was that, i'd say [how-can-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-undefined-or-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-can-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-undefined-or-null), but the title says otherwise, so does the code.

Comment: @cdhowie The index is coming from an API will be used to get a value from a static array.  I apologize for not being more descriptive but this is what I am looking for. I think `Number.IsInteger(indexValue)` would be better in my use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Since this is an index value, presumably you would like to accept any number.  This could suggest that `typeof indexValue === "number"` is the right approach, since this will reject both `null` and `undefined`, but will accept `0`. However, this condition will also accept other undesirable values, such as `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity`, which are all numbers as well.

Thankfully, the language provides us with a bulit-in function that can test all of these at once: [`isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite).  So your condition becomes:

```
if (isFinite(indexValue)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this function will accept strings that convert to finite numbers.  There is also [`Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite), which accepts only numbers, but is not supported in IE.  If you want to reject all strings, then combine the `isFinite()` check with the `typeof` check:

```
if (typeof indexValue === "number" && isFinite(indexValue)) {
    // ...
}
```