# Is there something similar to nullish coalescing operator but for if statements?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, we can do this

```
const someValue = null;
const myVal = someValue ?? "use this string if undefined or null";
```

and the result is:

```
console.log(myVal); // "use this string if undefined or null"
```

Is there a way I can check for null or undefined in an if statement without having to do

```
if(myVal !== null && myVal !== undefined) {
   // do something
}
```

? I cannot do a simple truthy check `if(myVal){}` because zero is a valid value for this variable.

Comment: `null == undefined` so you could look for `something == undefined` or `something != undefined` (or replace those with null). The double equals operator works, but the triple equals operator is strict

Comment: if you want also include the case of `""` is simple `if (myVal)`

Comment: @Eliseo The last sentence in the question explicitly mentions, why `if (myVal)` is not a valid solution in this case ...

Comment: Indeed the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-can-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-undefined-or-null
myVal == null, is exactly what I was looking for.