# "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'role')"

Tags: javascript, express, postman

**Code**

this is my code in VS code to check if the user is an admin or a user

```js
exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return next(
        new ErrorHandler(
          `Role: ${req.user.role} is not allowed to access this resource`,
          403
        )
      );
    }

    next();
  };
};
```

**Error in postman API**

the used declaration should be fine i don't know what's this problem

```
"success": false,
"message": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'role')"
```

Comment: how did you set the user ?

Comment: According to error, you are trying to access `role` property of `null` object. That means your `user` object is getting null value. From where are you getting `user` object? Are you getting it from body, or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume your `user` object on `req.user` is null, therefor it tries reading the property `role` of a null object.

Now, you can just check for `null` before validating the role, this way the API will at least return the correct error. (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2647888/6459948))

Something along the lines of (haven't tested the code):

```
if (null == req?.user?.role) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler(`Bad request`, 400));
}
```

But that still doesn't solve the issue for a valid request. For that I suggest you give us some more information on how you declare the request.

Comment: this is the default role i declared in my user model schema
```role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user",
  },```
and this is my user in the user controller
  ```const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    avatar: {
      public_id: "this is a sample id",
      url: "profilepicUrl",
    },
  });```
this is how it's saved in mongodb 
```name
:
"malek"
email
:
"6pp@test.com"
password
:
"$2a$10$8P9R2VjtDKf0b3EkukfSje7t3wswECEzdNAchsau17Kl79N.27RT."
avatar
:
Object
role
:
"user"```

still don't get the problem sadly.

Comment: @AdamThabet I assume those are test records and not your real credentials but I still get uncomfortable seeing a password and email posted like this ^^. Regarding your issue: 1) you could set a breakpoint in your controller to see weather your user actually gets created. Assuming he does (since its record is in the database apparently) you can 2) show us your Postman request (the issue might be invalid/incomplete request data) or 3) your backend - maybe also test that with a breakpoint - to see what you actually receive (i.e. there might be an encoding/decoding issue or something)

Answer (score 0):

I know where you are stuck ...

Go to ***auth.js*** file. In there use:

```
 req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);
```

instead of ***._id***

Answer (score 0):

req.user object is null that is why it showing this error. Make sure you obtain the user object in req.user.

You might have a function before your authorizeUser in that function make sure you obtain the user object in req.user

req.user = await User.findById(decodedData._id); //Check this line in your function and replace .id with ._id.