# Typescript generalize class member initialization

Tags: typescript

I want to modify the Blog-constructor from "[Minimal working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICEA2B7A5sgbwChlkxgxMIAuZAZzClFwG4TkFtwJxaGmQrIgF8iRUJFiIUqALLYAJhEyF2AbQDWEAJ59GzALq04IbW1FEIADwAO2KGA6Y4dOsnlLMACWU3oq0U4QBmRQCmA4TCw8AGEuGGBcWgwcfABeQlJSdnJKGmQAIgKAGnYgyF5CkuzhNiIEZ1dkaPxgAFsbKjaeMDcUvFVSXKoAQj0BIVJynrH6fUE6qa5+AFcEMHsACgU4MDhaAAU4BwjMAB45RWUAPmQMgmEASlUAehes9yvvX2gAOjCwLIIG0AEbQOibMAAC2AdGKyB2e3hANOLTiIASuEebFIogsVEcINSd2QIAgAHdmqlNgRhvkCpAGNVppUQCtMJgnkA)" below in a way that is described as "pseudo-code". How to initialize the members of class "Blog" via  generic ModelHelper class, so that I can rewrite the Blog constructor as:

pseudocode:

```
constructor(data: Partial<IModel> = {}) {
  ModelHelper.initMembers(this, data, initialBlogConfig);
}
export class ModelHelper {
  static initMembers<T, U>(model: T, data: Partial<IModel>, initialModel: U): void {
    for (key in initModel) {
      if(data[key] !== null && data[key] !== undefined) {
        model[key] = data[key];
      }else{
        model[key] = initialModel[key]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"Minimal working example":

```
interface IBlog {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
const initialBlogConfig: IBlog = {    
  title: "",
  content: "",  
};
interface IModel {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class Blog implements IBlog {
  title: string;
  content: string;

  constructor({title, content}: Partial<IModel> = {}) {
    this.title = title ?? "";
    this.content = content ?? "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a helper function to handle all aspects of property initialization for you, instead of using an initializer or directly assigning the properties inside the constructor, then the compiler won't be able to tell that the properties were initialized and you'll need to use a [definite assignment assertion (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) to suppress errors:

```
class Blog implements IBlog {
    title!: string;
    content!: string;
    constructor(data: NullableProps<IBlog> = {}) {
        ModelHelper.initMembers(this, data, { title: "", content: "" });
    }
}

let blog = new Blog({ title: "test", content: null })
console.log(blog); // {title: "test", content: ""}
```

where `NullableProps<T>` is a utility type of the form

```
type NullableProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] | null };
```

so that all properties are optional (so they can be missing or `undefined`) and nullable (so they can be `null` also).

---

If so then you can implement `initMembers()` in any number of ways.  Here's one way:

```
const ModelHelper = {
    initMembers<T extends object>(
        model: T, data: NullableProps<T>, initialConfig: T
    ): void {
        Object.assign(model,
            initialConfig,
            Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(data).filter(([_, v]) => v != null)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

You could write that as a `class` with a [`static`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) method if you really want to, but if you're not going to be using the class's constructor it's not necessary (like in Java) or particularly useful to do so.

The implementation above works by first copying all the properties from `initialConfig` into `model`, using [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and then by copying all the non-nullish properties from `data` into `model` (which were obtained by [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing the entries obtained from [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and converting back via [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)).

You can use `for` loops if you want, but you need to be careful to get all the keys from both `initialConfig` *and* from `data`, in case the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` type of `model` has any optional properties:

```
class Example {
    req1!: string;
    req2!: number;
    opt1?: boolean;
    opt2?: string;
    constructor(data: NullableProps<Example> = {}) {
        ModelHelper.initMembers(this, data, { req1: "a", req2: 1, opt1: false })
    }
}
let example = new Example({ opt2: "b" })
console.log(example) // {req1: "a", req2: 1, opt1: false, opt2: "b"}
```

Any implementation would need to make sure to copy both `opt1` and `opt2` appropriately.

---

On the other hand, if you don't mind using a field initializer to handle the `initialConfig` defaults, then you can forgo the assertions and just have `initMembers` handle the partial input:

```
class Blog implements IBlog {
    title = "";
    content = "";
    constructor(data: NullableProps<IBlog> = {}) {
        ModelHelper.initMembers(this, data);
    }
}

let blog = new Blog({ title: "test", content: null });
console.log(blog); // {title: "test", content: ""}

const ModelHelper = {
    initMembers<T extends object>(
        model: T, data: NullableProps<T>
    ): void {
        Object.assign(model,
            Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(data).filter(([_, v]) => v != null)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This is easier to get right with a `for` loop, since there's only the `data` argument to worry about, so you only need to iterate over its keys:

```
const ModelHelper = {
    initMembers<T extends object>(
        model: T, data: NullableProps<T>
    ): void {
        for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data) as Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]>) {
            if (v != null) model[k] = v;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICEA2B7A5sgbwChlTkxgxMIAuZAZzClFwG4SyFtwJw7HmINkQC+RImACeABxQA5AK6ZMcAEbUAClGzT6AHgAqAPmQBeQsgDaAaWShkAawiTsMZAYC6AfjoGbH5AAfZBAlTGQRdiIQOABbCHppRBQADUJxMmQuEEZkAFlsABMITAAJEtkoM3TMzNBKPIhY1Wh9A2QIAA9IEEL6ZGxVACsIBDAjAAoOWtrYopLfABpkQrgwODpFZTVNbV1DI2X6ijhMAGFuGGBcX2nagEo6ADdsYEKamdqAeWHRsAA6OD0ejXEATObFTCLO6fWrHYCnC4gK64aGw2E-EZjf4wbSxACi4GYCSm6LJyExf3+vCYwBJq3W9xxwEwkCgEwmlgA+ssnh57mYTE9kABCcyhZT3GHkqXk5D3diwsSZMR3BAqYHILB4OyxaTUeLgfoYHD4YiwihUCAi-i0oSKz7ZHpgG0MO3CWHZAQKMbYdkMjbILYqdQQLQ6fQmvAmcwEEQC83kgqQ8qYSr-Y6NZqtCZgAAWwHoywDywI5Eo1DoACIq8snTTq1WIgrpaRlWRVZlqGBkOodeKIAB3LWmiZly2V5BVyCMWtZbjOugS8LxtXcejYaj-Ud93AK5AAegPhAntCnM7Ac-rfCnVdVao1-XxnTi+pQiZmUAgAEcAIyugQWAdT8fwAJldUJsygYDah0MBfx8XtsE3CA4BAGDMjg0DEMA+1W3nHImB9MA-QmANNjCHYwz2fRn1fagY0IeMPjJZMSlTdNMyaFooHoXMCyLFY1jgUtkC-P9qzgOdxNAuhf2WODfzoeBMHoFBVyVO521IbsOhfPVqGqEAh2QOiDIgMcBmkMBZKnVQmw0zh1xQ7c8AmLp6IgAUj0IcSlKnKTlhkuSFOs-yVLU0KbOrez71VGJ4kSZJkAATRYgjcjYsoKmgaoPzhEAGm41pDD0no+gGX4xkmfDMghBZ3GLYSKO2UNw32Yx8MeZAXjedKMSqgEgRBXAwXqqFas+SlsVxbACSJOk+MmslpoBGliT4gMmSuVloA5bleX5QUetFcUwllOUyAuskW00lVxAfYaRx1YBzMNMBjW1M18NPaoawwpyeHAP6qwB0gvSI31-WaoNKLami9CjXBGLjBNlvyeZsrTaAM0KsAsx4vj80LJrGTBiItIyMhdN3IyTK+yzT2rC8rwXBsQjCZsYK9Fyd1NfcfIIJnzwSS86zZm8a07ThH1M-S336sg-L+qT8Jk6pf3wxTENUZDqDQ6oIogcmsJw91yYhqBiNI8jYda3YIz0My3xR5j8thLKOJxrioKJgTSbgW7Pm0imuwgHsPPMunh2d6hLKwmKHOujLebcyO32848CD8yTpLAkKrPg5TTkiwvbKrWLRAehKEiSJBkAALXSiGMZTHKqljfCfcJ0qunK-pBixcZSXJcaliE9YWpDB2OqMLrnled53c+GA-WQCYW8sBxDoGNxVupBb6WEgUgWQABBKAoDgSQ9C35xXEa9w75cNxPA8Iw0cushgDcCZhTFDmkpkDjS3gEcwTxyb3Tuh2B6mR1RPS+rqN871PqmkVqQX65h-r4WvD2LBoMcHrkhiRaGk87bT2oo7JGrtP5Jkxl7KAuMiq+34iTCegdyYh2ljpcOvY0EDmHAzccFYzzTlFqzIGYAlyc3jNzZyW4+Z4AFlnYWYjZzi0kY2bhWRZax3fGrH8v4VZVgMd+UCGstZhR1nrVCIBDYl2NpYmyZtBAekdEQq2UMyIw2DFRdqtF5YMTym7dGnt25MPxsVXirDBJbU4ZTMOEdAkoAEXLTy8drLl3ss2NcORU64HcskzOvlDG5yCvnZA8lC7hQcVFLJd5RBAA)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Last question, why there is no explicit check if `...&& v != undefined` or why does `new Blog({ title: "test", content: undefined });` not sets content to `undefined`? In this context is `new Blog({ title: "test", content: undefined });` same as `new Blog({ title: "test" });`?

Comment: Note that it's `!=` and not `!==`.  Writing `v != null` checks for both `null` and `undefined` because of the behavior of the loose inequality operator.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647867/2887218).