# How to redirect a page based on browser used

Tags: user-agent, redirect

I have a page on my site that doesn't display well when viewed from Mozilla Firefox. I have some jQuery codes that don't work on Mozilla. It displays well on Some other browsers.

I am wondering if there is a way I can redirect my visitors who use Mozilla to an alternate URL where I will remove the jQuery code.

Pls any help?

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is supposed to be platform-agnostic. If the Firefox you're talking about isn't ten years old it is *very* likely the underlying problem can be fixed, making the redirection unnecessary.

Comment: I understand but I'm not sure who will be viewing the site. Most users are not aware to update their browser. That's why.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? Take an approach similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779631/redirect-ps3-via-user-agent

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean  the underlying problem can't easily be fixed.

Comment: @EstheronsSamuel have you checked which versions access your site ? Normally Firefox updates automatically

Comment: And by the way: @Pekka웃 is right, you should not avoid the problem, better fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript user agent redirect by browser version number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719118/javascript-user-agent-redirect-by-browser-version-number)