# How to check if javascript variable exist, empty, array, (array but empty), undefined, object and so on

Tags: javascript, error-handling, operators

How to check if javascript variable exist, empty, array, (array but empty), undefined, object and so on

As mentioned in the title, I need a general overview how to check javascript variables in several cases without returning any error causing the browser to stop processing the pageload.
(now I have several issues in this topic.

For example IE stops with error in case _os is undefined, other browsers doesnt:

```
var _os = fbuser.orders;

var o =0;
var _ret = false;
for (var i = 0; i < _os.length; i++){
...
```

Furthermore i also need a guide of the proper using operators like == , ===.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript

Comment: This isn't "give me a guide".com. What research have you done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As mentioned in the title, I need a general overview how to check
>   javascript variables in several cases without returning any error
>   causing the browser to stop processing the pageload.

To check whether or not variables is there, you can simply use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof _os != 'undefined'){
  // your code
}
```

The `typeof` will also help you avoid `var undefined` error when checking that way.

---

> Furthermore i also need a guide of the proper using operators like ==
>   , ===.

Both are equality operators. First one does *loose* comparison to check for values while latter not only checks *value* but also *type* of operands being compared.

Here is an example:

```
4 == "4" // true
4 === "4" // false because types are different eg number and string
```

With `==` javascript does type cohersion automatically. When you are sure about type and value of both operands, always use strict equality operator eg `===`.

---

Generally, using `typeof` is [problematic](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/), you should ONLY use it to check whether or not a variables is present.

Read More at MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` operator is very helpful here:

```
typeof asdf
// "undefined"
```

Perhaps you want something like this in your case:

```
// Handle cases where `fbuser.orders` is not an array:
var _os = fbuser.orders || []
```