# Javascript - Shorthand notation to safely check/access a property on a potential undefined object

Tags: javascript

What's the shortest syntax to check if *jsonObject* is not undefined before accessing its errorMessage property?

```
var jsonObject = SomeMethodReturningAnObject();

if (jsonObject.errorMessage === undefined) // jsonObject can be undefined and this will throw an error
   /* success! */
else
   alert(jsonObject.errorMessage);
```

Comment: `if(!jsonObject.errorMessage)` ?

Comment: @androidavid reading the errorMessage property on a undefined or null object will throw an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `&&` operator, since it doesn't evaluate the right-hand side if the left-hand side is `undefined`:

```
if (jsonObject && jsonObject.errorMessage === undefined)
```

Comment: Might be able to skip the `=== undefined` too.

Comment: @Douglas: I guess that will do the opposite. The OP is checking whether there is no error (which means success).

Comment: What does the && operator do?

Comment: @contactmatt: Evaluate the left hand side and if it's falsy, evaluate to the right hand side (and evaluate to the left hand side otherwise). `undefined` is falsy, so it won't trigger the expression that would rise an error in that case.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the error "Cannot read property 'errorMessage' of undefined

Comment: @contactmatt did you tried my answer? I suspect your problem is in the alert function, on the else clause

Comment: @contactmatt: If `jsonObject` is undefined, does that mean "success" or not?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to use the `typeof` operator.

In JS if a variable has been declared but not set a value, such as:

`var x;`

Then `x` is set to `undefined` so you can check for it easily by:

```
if(x) //x is defined
if(!x) //x is undefined
```

However if you try to do `if(x)` on a variable that hasn't even been declared, you'll get the error you allude to in your post, *"ReferenceError: x is not defined"*.

In this case we need to use `typeof` - [MSDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) - to check.

So in your case something like:

```
if(typeof jsonObject !== "undefined") {
    //jsonObject is set
    if(jsonObject.errorMessage) {
        //jsonObject set, errorMessage also set
    } else {
        //jsonObject set, no errorMessage!
    }
} else {
    //jsonObject didn't get set
}
```

This works because if you have a variable set to an empty object, `x={}`, and try to get at a variable within that object that doesn't exist, eg `x.y`, you get `undefined` returned, you don't get a ReferenceError.

Be aware that the `typeof` operator returns a string denoting the variable type, not the type itself. So it would return `"undefined"` not `undefined`.

Also, this very similar question on SO that could help you: [How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)

Hope this helps.

Jack.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonObject = SomeMethodReturningAnObject();

if (jsonObject && jsonObject.errorMessage === undefined)
   /* success! */
else
   alert(!jsonObject ? "jsonObject not defined" : jsonObject.errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jsonObject)
{
    if (!jsonObject.errorMessage)
        // success..
        foo()    
    else
        alert(jsonObject.errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the *shorthand notation* aspect as your specific situation is better served by [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589568/2194007). As of ECMAScript 2018 we have [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which makes the whole thing much more concise:

```js
if ( {...jsonObject}.errorMessage ) {
    // we have errorMessage
} else {
    // either jsonObject or jsonObject.errorMessage are undefined / falsey
    // in either case, we don't get an exception
}
```

A straight if / else is not the perfect fit for your situation because you actually have 3 states, 2 of which are crammed into the same if branch above.

1. No `jsonObject`: Failure
2. Has `jsonObject`, has no `errorMessage`: Success
3. Has `jsonObject`, has `errorMessage`: Failure

#### Why this works:

Accessing a property `foo` from an object `obj`, assuming the object is undefined, is essentially doing this:

```js
undefined.foo //exception, obviously
```

Spread syntax copies properties to a new object, so you end up with an object *no matter what*:

```js
typeof {...undefined} === 'object'
```

So by spreading `obj` you avoid operating directly on a potentially `undefined` variable.

#### Some more examples:

```js
({...undefined}).foo  // === undefined, no exception thrown

({...{'foo': 'bar'}}).foo // === 'bar'
```