# Find out where a javascript object gets created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to find out where (in which function or in which file) a javascript object gets created or a variable gets defined?

I am working on a website where a variable foo gets created and is available in the chrome dev tools console when I add a div with the id foo. But I can not find out where that happens. It has to be in one of the plugins.

Comment: Try this post see if it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser creates global vars for every html tag with an id or name, so if you have a `<div id="foo" />` the browser will create a `foo` object that references the `div`, just as if you did `var foo = document.getElementById('foo');`

Comment: Firefox doesn't do this, but you're right that others (Chrome in particular) do.

Comment: It's a really terrible thing that they do it, too :)

Comment: @Pointy, I couldn't agree with you more... implicit global variable creation is probably one of the worst headscratchers in JS and browsers

Comment: Ha ha yes, though I've come to think of it as a great motivation to write most code inside closures :)

Comment: @Pointy true. BTW I tested your comment in firefox (latest version) and apparently it does create a variable for each element. you can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dL96d/

Comment: Wow, that must be somewhat new (or else my brain is broken?).  I think my brain is OK because there are a bunch of old SO questions regarding code that worked in IE and Chrome but not Firefox, and that was the reason.