# JSON object filter

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to ask you how to filter value from these JSON

```
{first: "100", second: "200", third: "300"}
```

I mean that I need something like this

```
if(json=first){select value}
```

I wrote this part to explain you what I need. I hope that you understand me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you need the value of the `first` property? `yourObject.first`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if

```
var json = {first: "100", second: "200", third: "300"};
var valueFromSlider = "first";

if(json[valueFromSlider] !== undefined) {
    // The valueFromSlider i.e. "first" exists in the json object.
    alert(json[valueFromSlider]); //alerts 100
}
```

See null/undefined checking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/858193

I think what you are trying to do should look like this.

```
var json = {100: "first", 200: "second", 300: "third"};
var valueFromSlider = 100;

if(json[valueFromSlider] !== undefined) {
    // The valueFromSlider i.e. 100 exists in the json object.
    alert(json[valueFromSlider]); //alerts "first"
}
```

---

**Console output**

> var json = {first: "100", second: "200", third: "300"};
>
> json.first
>   *"100"*
>
> json["first"]
>   *"100"*
>
> json.first === "100"
>   *true*
>
> json.first !== undefined
>   *true*
>
> json.another !== undefined
>   *false*

Comment: Yes I know but I do not know that there is some value called first. I need to find if there is.

Comment: Sorry but I think that it is not what I need. I try to explain one more. I have value which is changing we can call it value then I have json object and I need to find if in json object exist this value which is changing and if exist then write this value into some DIV. Do you understand what I want? Thank you for your help

Comment: @folpy I don't really understand what it is you are trying to do. if not undefined tells you if an item exists.

Comment: I try to explain it from beginning. I have jquery form slider which give some value and then I have this JSON object. What I need is to searching value from jquery form slider in JSON object. Now you understand what I want to do? Again thank you for your help

Comment: @folpy So I've updated my answer again I think this is what you mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help. This is exactly what I need. Again thank you.