# ExpressJS + EJS: Avoid "variable is not defined" globally

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How to globally avoid EJS throw error when context variable is not defined ? I mean a way to set (in middleware?) for example space or null value for all variables not defined. Now i always use on template something like below. Is better way ?

```
<% if(typeof locals.variable != 'undefined') { %>
 ... 
<% } %>
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I usually just have a middleware that sets some default values for a particular set of routes via `res.locals.variable = undefined;` or similar. Then you can successfully check `if (variable === undefined)` in the template for those routes.