# Does JavaScript have something similar to the null propagating operating in C#?

Tags: javascript, syntax, null-propagation-operator

I have a lot of pieces of JavaScript like

```
 if(myobject != undefined && myobject.someprop == something)
```

and I'm wondering if there exists syntax to make this more compact (even if it's a "hack" of some sort).

Comment: You could simplify this to `if (myobject && myobject.someprop == something)`, but there is no similar operator in Javascript.

Comment: Hmm, didn't really mean to use the dupe-hammer there, but you've tagged the question C#. Does the link answer your question?

Comment: Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#get).

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like:

```
if(myobject && myobject.someprop == something)
```

Or `typeof` validation:

```
if(typeof myobject != 'undefined' && myobject.someprop == something)
```

Checking an object's property within a valid object:

```
if(myobject && myobject.hasOwnProperty('your_property'))
```

You have a lot of possibilities in verifying objects or variables, but the all the operators work in that way in Javascript..

Here you can see more detailed ways to code your validation:
[How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)