# Javascript - how to check variable is not declared before

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load images with javascript, first I get wide size image url and when user open the moda then I'm gonna load wide size images.

I'm try to do it with below way

```
try {
    images
}
catch(err) {
    if (err.name == "ReferenceError"){
        let images = [];
        let nodes = tab.childNodes[1].children;
        for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].firstElementChild.className === "slider") {
                images.push(nodes[i].firstElementChild.src)
            }
        }
        Images:load(images)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, loads images every time.

I try put these codes inside of these if statement but none of them didn't work too, they gave `Uncaught ReferenceError: images is not defined at HTMLElement.<anonymous>` error

```
if (typeof images == 'undefined')

if (typeof images === undefined)

if (typeof images == 'undefined' || images.lenth === 0 )
```

is there any way to check images variable not declared before ?

Comment: How come you don't know whether or not `images` variable is declared?

Comment: @raina77ow if images variable defined, I know images already loaded, if not, then I'm gonna load images

Comment: The first if statement does not produce an error

Comment: @LucaKiebel yes but second and third throws

Comment: seems like not the best design.  A variable can be set to undefined...

Comment: @raina77ow is there any good practise that to check images are loaded ?

Comment: @HasanTıngır yes. Store a reference to the nodes in an object based on url and check that: `{ "/img/img1.png": imgDOMNode }`

Comment: @akaphenom I'm totally open to advices :) I'm beginner at javascript

Comment: Change `let images = [];` to `images = [];` in the `catch` section, so that you do not create a new variable but use the already defined `images`

Comment: What do you mean by loading images with javascript? do you making some ajax request that returns images to you or what? "first I get wide size image url and when user open the moda then I'm gonna load wide size images." that phrase is unclear.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you, it gave an idea to solve my problem

Comment: All the answers DO answer your question, but don't actually solve your problem. You should never (barring few exceptions) check whether or not variable is declared; instead you should check _value_ of this variable. And if you want to do something whenever your images are loaded, just handle their `load` event.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
    // variable is defined
}
```

Comment: `let foo; typeof foo /* undefined */; let foo; // ERROR: foo has already been declared`

Answer (score -1):

GreatDharmatma is correct. Checking if the variable's type is strictly equal to 'undefined' would help solving your problem.

```
if (typeof something !== 'undefined') {
    // do stuff when variable was declared
} else {
    // do stuff when variables was not declared
}
```

I would also suggest you take a look at this question: [How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)

It has a lot of explanations about `undefined`, not declared and `null` variables in javascript.

Comment: No, that is not correct. See my comment on that answer.

Comment: You're right! I misunderstood the complete case! Thanks!