# Function.keys to check if a variable data exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the `Object` class of JavaScript to check if a variable exists before using it from a JSON response.
When I try to call that line of code I get this error

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>     at Function.keys ()
>     at successCallback

Here is my attempt:

```
if (Object.keys(response.data.data.user_fk)) {
  $rootScope.username = response.data.data.user_fk.name;
}
```

Please how can I get the check right?

Comment: Can you please tell what is the value of `response.data.data.user_fk`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a not-defined variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: If you're trying to check whether `user_fk` is a property of `response.data.data`, then `Object.keys()` is not useful. You can test `"user_fk" in response.data.data` instead.

Comment: The goal is to test user_fk in response.data.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if `response.data.data.user_fk` exists just use:

```js
if (response.data.data.user_fk) {
    $rootScope.username=response.data.data.user_fk.name;
}
```

Be aware that if user_fk is a false or a 0 (everything that results to `false` when called within Boolean function), this will not trigger code inside if.

```js
Boolean(0) //false
Boolean(false) //false
Boolean([]) //true
Boolean({}) //true
Boolean(true) //true
```

In such cases just compare it to undefined or null:

```
if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
    //Execute code that uses value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if(Object.keys(response.data.data.user_fk)){
...
```

With given question I only can say that

`response` or `response.data` or `response.data.data` or `response.data.data.user_fk` is `undefined` or `null`

So probably you receive null somewhere or missing data during some manipulations.
But in provided question there is **not enough data** to answer more concrete