# How to check if token is undefined for user authentication

Tags: reactjs

I can log in user if it enters correct password but when I enter wrong password it shows me "access_token" is undefined.

This is my useToken.js file

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useToken() {

  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.access_token;
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', JSON.stringify(userToken.data));
    setToken(userToken.data.access_token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }

}
```

This is inside my Login.js file where I handle this submit

```
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const token = await loginUser({
          email,
          password
        });
        setToken(token);
      }
```

And finally in my App.js file I show login page by:

```
  if (!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }
```

How can I check for undefined if they enter wrong password or username redirect to login page.

Comment: log `userToken` and see

Comment: It shows same error when I enter a wrong password. https://imgur.com/a/tZB2OqP

Comment: The error is "cannot read access_token of undefined", which means `userToken.data` is undefined. This is most likely because the password is wrong. use `userToken?.data?.access_token`

Comment: Thanks this is working! It was the optional values that did the trick since I wasn't putting those ```?``` there.

Comment: cool, ill post it as answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error is "cannot read access_token of undefined", which means
> userToken.data is undefined. This is most likely because the password
> is wrong. use the following.

```
userToken?.data?.access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript). Once managed to write a logic for isUndefined, embed it with a ternary operator like:

```
{ isUndefined ?
    // do these if true
    :
    // do these if false
}
```

Comment: I've given that a go before but there is something else wrong here aside from checking for undefined since it still is showing me undefined.