# How to check whether the variable is defined or not before assigning in Java Script ?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Here on page load i am trying to store the values from form to variables. Later i would like to use those variables (if and only if i have data in that) to other purpose.

This is how i approached ( on page load )

```
render : function() {
 frm = document.Form;

 if (frm.Name1.value){
                value1 = frm.Name1.value;
        }
 if (frm.Name2.value){
            value2 = frm.Name2.value;
        }
if (frm.Name3.value){
            value3 = frm.Name3.value;
        } 

}
```

Based on certain condition / selection i will call this function to assign initially loaded values

```
function add_values ( ) {
      if (value1.length){
            frm.Name1.value = value1;
        }
       if (value2.length){
            frm.Name2.value = value2;
        }
        if (value3.length){
            frm.Name3.value = value3;
        }
}
```

Error: ( in firebug )

```
value3 is not defined
[Break On This Error] if (value3.length){
```

What did i try ?

```
if (undefined != value3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a variable is defined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
if(typeof value3 != "undefined")
```

more on [typeof](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml)

Comment: typeof is exactly what it sounds like. it returns the type of the variable in string format. see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof so in this case if typeof returns "undefined" then you know it was not previously set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
typeof value3 != 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if something is undefined:

```
if (typeof value3 === 'undefined') {
    // It's undefined!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the variable's type is `undefined`:

```
if (typeof value3 !== 'undefined') {
  // value3 is defined
}
```

If you want, you can make a PHP-like function for that:

```
function isset(variable) {
  return typeof variable !== 'undefined';
}

if (isset(value3)) {
  // value3 is defined
}
```