# Dynamically change a link in Jquery Mobile via Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a link in the header of my index.htm page that goes to page_02.htm. When the user reaches page_02.htm a variable is set to true. When the user returns to the index.htm from page_02 I wish to check if the variable is in fact true and dynamically update the href and text of the button in the header.

This seems like a very basic task, however I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to refresh the index.htm page without having to force page reload. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your variable declared?  What's it scope?  When you come back to index.htm from page_02, can you validate that the pageshow event is being fired?  If you work out those two issues... you should be 99% of the way there.

Comment: @deathtrap, was the answer posted below helpful towards getting your answer? If so, please accept it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could check to see if a variable [is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript) in `pagebeforeshow` and if it is then you can act upon it however you see fit.

```
$("#homePage").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event) {
    if (typeof some_global != 'undefined') {
        alert(some_global);
    }
});
```

In my secondary page, all I did was

```
var some_global = "Made it here";
```