# Better way to see if an object is present in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is

```
if(!!object)
{
 // do something if object found
}
```

a much more guarenteed way to see if any object is present?

```
if(object)
{

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a variable is defined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

the safest way to check that something is defined:

```
if (typeof thingy !== 'undefined')
```

Comment: why wouldn't !thingy catch this case?

Comment: @kunj2aan Consider the different outcome when dealing with a variable containing the value `false` or any falsy value.  If you can make some assumption about your variable then other methods are fine.  For instance, the result of `getElementById` will often just use `if(result)` because you know it will never return false or 0.

Comment: @kunj2aan `!thingy` will throw an exception if thingy has not been defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof my_var == 'object'){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to check that...

```
if ( object )
if ( !!object )
if ( object !== undefined )
if ( typeof object !== 'undefined' )
if ( object !== void 0 )
if ( {}.toString.apply( object ).subtr( 0, 7 ) === '[object' )
```

Etc.