# How to init a global variable if it is not present?

Tags: javascript

I load the same script in my page many times. I have some trouble on decide which is loaded first/after in my website, due to the async/load functions.

So, I'd like to put a global variable that count, when the script is loaded, the order of them.

So myScript.js will start with :

```
(function () {
    var privateNumberScriptLoaded;

    if (numberScriptLoaded === undefined) {
        numberScriptLoaded = 0;
    }
    else {
        numberScriptLoaded = numberScriptLoaded + 1;
    }

    privateNumberScriptLoaded = numberScriptLoaded;
    console.log(privateNumberScriptLoaded);
})();
```

but when I load it with :

```
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget/myScript.js?type=normal" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget/myScript.js?type=rotation" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get (for two times) `numberScriptLoaded is not defined`.

How can I resolve this trouble? In fact I'll "create" a global variable in my website if it doesnt exist. Than increment it and store in a "private" variable for each script, so I can save the order of the execution for each script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a variable is defined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At present, your script falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). I'd recommend not doing that.

You have three options:

1. As all global variables end up as properties on `window`, you could use `window` explicitly:

   ```
   if (!window.numberScriptLoaded) {
       window.numberScriptLoaded = 1; // 1, not 0
   }
   else {
       ++window.numberScriptLoaded;
   }
   ```

   Unlike the code without the `window.` prefix, that won't throw a `ReferenceError`, because looking up a property on an object works differently from resolving a freestanding identifier.

   [Live demo](http://jsbin.com/uyokiv) | [demo page source](http://jsbin.com/uyokiv/edit) | [source of script it loads](http://jsbin.com/isevaq/edit)
2. Always put `var numberScriptLoaded;` (with no initializer) at global scope in your script, e.g. outside your scoping function:

   ```
   var numberScriptLoaded; // No initializer (no = 0 or anything)
   ```

   On the first load, this will create the variable; on subsequent loads, it's a no-op. Then you can do this without a `ReferenceError`:

   ```
   if (!numberScriptLoaded) {
       numberScriptLoaded = 1; // 1, not 0
   }
   else {
       ++numberScriptLoaded;
   }
   ```

   [Live demo](http://jsbin.com/uyokiv/2) | [demo page source](http://jsbin.com/uyokiv/2/edit) | [source of script it loads](http://jsbin.com/isevaq/2/edit)
3. Use `typeof`. If you take the `typeof` a variable that doesn't exist, you don't get a `ReferenceError`; you get `"undefined"`. Then you can create it via the `window.` prefix (so you're not falling prey to *The Horror*).

   ```
   if (typeof numberScriptLoaded === "undefined") {
       // Assigning to window.numberScriptLoaded creates the global
       window.numberScriptLoaded = 1; // 1, not 0
   }
   else {
       ++numberScriptLoaded;
   }
   ```

   [Live demo](http://jsbin.com/uyokiv/3) | [demo page source](http://jsbin.com/uyokiv/3/edit) | [source of script it loads](http://jsbin.com/isevaq/3)

Comment: `2 - Always put var numberScriptLoaded; (with no initializer) at global scope in your script.` : i need this variable "global" for the whole website, so the next script loaded can access to this variable.

Comment: P.S. in fact, except "typeof", I'm following the 3° option. What's wrong?

Comment: @markzzz: Re your first comment: Right, that's why I'm saying you put it at global scope. So it's a global. Re your second comment: See what I wrote; without `typeof`, you're trying to reference an identifier that isn't in scope, resulting in a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: How can you put a variable in global scope without "var"?

Comment: @markzzz: By assigning to a property on the global object, which is the container of all global variables. On browsers, there's a global variable, `window`, that refers to the global object. (It's a property the object uses to point to itself.) So `window.foo = 2;` creates a global variable called `foo` with the value `2`. I've added demos of all three options for you.

Comment: Honestly I read in deep that article about "horror", but really, I don't understand why this "Horror". Using `window.numberScriptLoaded = 1` or `numberScriptLoaded = 1` in fact doesnt make any differences. So why using `window.`? Can you give to me an example?

Comment: @markzzz: The horror doesn't primarily relate to whether you use `window` or not. Say you have a global variable called `label`. In a function, you try to set the value of this variable, and you write `lable = "Hi there";` ***Boom***, you have a hard-to-find, silent bug, because rather than doing what any reasonable system would do and throwing an error for the undefined symbol `lable`, classic JS just happily creates a new global called `lable`. Fortunately, the new strict mode fixes this error. But if you really meant to create an ad hoc global, using `window` helps make your intent clear.

Comment: So, it's just a discussion about the easily on read code and find scope! Well, I've thought in some that generate error ;)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `typeof`

```
if (typeof numberScriptLoaded === 'undefined') {
```

Comment: usually this work as well `window.jQuery === undefined`. What's the difference?

Comment: 1) What's the point of using much slower === when typeof always returns string? 2) isn't `if(numberScriptLoaded===undefined)` a quicker/shorter/better solution?

Comment: The only difference is that `undefined` can be overwritten.  `undefined = 5; window.jQuery === undefined;` compares the variable against 5 instead of testing if it is undefined.  Since `undefined` is global, the fear is that a (stupid) library may overwrite it and you would not know.

Comment: @chester1000 much slower? compare to what?

Comment: @chester1000 `if(numberScriptLoaded===undefined)` will give you a undefined error.

Comment: @chester1000 `===` is fast than `==`, the speed does not depends on how many `=` it has. :)

Comment: @xdazz: You're right it will work only on object proporties: `var a={}; if(a.sth==undefined){}`. Also, therein fact is a performance difference between `==` and `===`, but previously I was wrong, `===` is faster, because it doesn't perform type conversion first. :)

Comment: Oh, yes, @xdazz brings up a good point -- understand the difference between a *variable name that has not been defiend* and an *existing variable whose type is `undefined`*.  The check `myvar === undefined` will give an error if the variable named `myvar` has never been defined with `var myvar;` or similar.  By contrast, `typeof` handles both cases just fine.

Comment: @apsillers: As I said before, it works only with object fields, but if you'd like to check any variable that way, just use it as window property: `if( window.sth===undefined ) {`

Comment: @chester1000: Not *any* variable. Just global variables.

Comment: @chester1000: *"1) What's the point of using much slower `===` when typeof always returns string?"* Slower than what? "*2) isn't `if(numberScriptLoaded===undefined)` a quicker/shorter/better solution?"* Not if `numberScriptLoaded` isn't in scope, no; that's the reason the OP is getting a `ReferenceError` thrown in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if ( 'undefined' === typeof numberScriptLoaded ) {
    numberScriptLoaded = 0;
} else {
    numberScriptLoaded = numberScriptLoaded + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myGlobalVar = typeof myGlobalVar == "undefined"? "New Value" : myGlobalVar;
myGlobalVar = typeof myGlobalVar == "undefined"? "Totally New Value" : myGlobalVar;
alert(myGlobalVar);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gnuwaah/2/

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are direct attributes of `window` object. So if you'd like to init global variable from anywhere just type:

```
window.variableName = "what_ever_you_want"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice and to prevent this type of errors, all variables should be initialized before being used in your script.

You should put:

```
var numberScriptLoaded;
```

Just before your closure and the error won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the `window` to store the global, then you can do it in a single line with:

```
window.numberScriptLoaded  = (window.numberScriptLoaded  || 0) + 1
```