# How can I easily set a variable to false with a default of true?

Tags: javascript, properties, boolean

I usually set object properties like so,

```
// Boolean
this.listening = config.listening || true;
```

But `config.listening` is either true or false, and in this case `this.listening` will always be true because if `config.listening` is false it will equal true.

Is there a better way to set these boolean properties without having to do an if statement?

Is there a if isset function in javascript to check it exists rather than what it equals to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the ternary (conditional) operator like this:

```
this.listening = config.listening === false ? false : true;
```

If `config.listening` is `false`, `this.listening` is set to `false`. If it's any other value, it's set to `true`.

If you want to check if it's defined, you could use:

```
this.listening = typeof config.listening !== "undefined"
```

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: ha. Webstorm just simplified your answer to:   config.listening !== false , seems to be correct.

Comment: @AlexMills You're absolutely right! Condensing is definitely possible, I was just trying to be explicit/descriptive when I wrote this (I'm guessing)

Comment: I prefer explicit and you should keep your answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to check to make sure it is not undefined, not that it is a "falsey" value.

```
this.listening = config.listening!==undefined ? config.listening : true;
```

Comment: ... or `'listening' in config` possibly

Comment: Would it be better to do `typeof config.listening !== "undefined"` or is that just a readability factor

Comment: Yes, it would be better. (Or 'listening' in config). See this question for a discussion on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Comment: typeof would not be "better"unless you are scared that someone in an older browser is going to hijack your undefined.

Comment: Also the direct test runs faster in modern browsers than typeof