# How can I set an if the query string is does come up as something other than

Tags: javascript

How can I make a javascript if function where if the query string does show as something other than undefined. Here is the code:

```
    var getQueryString = window.location.href.split("?")[1];
alert(getQueryString);
```

Basically I wanted to do an if function in javascript. Here is the code:

```
    if (getQueryString = 1){
          //add code
    }
```

How can I set my javascript function?

Comment: Im a bit lost, can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: basically if I there is no query string on the url and the alert comes up as undefined I wanted to do an if undefined.

Comment: Err, undefined is falsy, no need to check for 1 (or set to 1) ?

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript)

Comment: 1. You should not name variables as if they were methods. Verbs should be used for method names only. 2. You are assigning `1` here; for comparison use `==` or `===`. 3. You need to compare against `undefined`; for compatibility and safety (the `undefined` property has not always been read-only), use the `typeof` operator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bellow code should work for you

```
var getQueryString = window.location.href.split("?")[1];

if (typeof getQueryString !== 'undefined')
{
    //Your code goes here
} else [
  alert("Query String not set");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `location.search` and check it's `length` instead of your approach.

```
if (window.location.search.slice(1).length > 0) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Currently, your code will always execute because you're setting `getQueryString` to 1 instead of comparing it. Even if you were comparing it, it would still be false since `getQueryString` is a string and not a number.

Comment: `location.search` may be `"?"` if there is no query part. Also, it should be `window.location.search`.

Comment: "May be" does not mean "must be", so in theory you need to trim the leading `?` and then compare the length. Everything is easier with regular expression matching, though.

Comment: `location.search` returns an empty string even if there's just a `?` at the end of the url. I changed it back to 0.

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions. This feature originates from DOM Level 0. There is no specification (that I am aware of), and implementations have been varying over the years.

Comment: You're totally right. I just tried it in IE9 and it returned just the `?`. I adjusted my code.

Comment: Adjusted. As far as I know it's just a matter of taste, though.

Comment: It is a capital mistake to assume that the ECMAScript Global Object would in general be the same object as the `window` object. And consider local variables.