# Check if part of an object is defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a variable:

```
latestPostId = posts[latestPost].post_id
```

But in one scenario, it is not defined yet. What is the best way to check?

I have tried these:

```
if (data.post_id !== undefined) {
if (data.post_id !== 'undefined') {
if (typeof data.post_id != 'undefined') {
```

But none seem to work. What is the best way to check if `posts[latestPost].post_id` is defined?

Comment: `if (posts && latestPost in posts && 'post_id' in posts[latestPost])`

Comment: Check out this question and explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript test for existence of nested object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to check if posts[latestPost].post_id is defined?

Does `posts[latestPost].post_id !== undefined` work?

I would probably do `posts[latestPost] && posts[latestPost].post_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways (your last one is ok):

```
   if (typeof data.post_id != 'undefined')
```

Or simpler

```
   if (data.post_id)
```

BUT: This may generate an error, if data does not exist at all. So you should do:

```
   if (data && data.post_id)
```

For an object like: a.b.c.d.e.f, you should do:

```
   if (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d && etc)
```

Comment: typeof is not a function

Comment: check it in your console

Comment: but you are right... js doc says is operator. my bad. => edited answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not working, but you wrote "your last one was close", and it wasn't close, it was correct, yours is wrong, `typeof` is still not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper to avoid long `if` statements and improve re-usability, something like:

```
/**
 * @param {string} key
 * @param {object} obj
 */
function keyExists(key, obj) {
  var res = key.split('.').reduce(function(acc,x) {
    return acc[x];    
  },obj);
  return res != null || false;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var obj = {a: {b: {c:'foo'}}};

console.log(keyExists('a.b.c', obj)); //=> true
console.log(keyExists('a.b.c.d', obj)); //=> false

if (keyExists('a.b.c', obj)) {
  // it exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator checks an object for a property.

```
'post_id' in posts[latestPost]`
```

Some people prefer `hasOwnProperty`. `in` traverses an object's prototype chain, while `hasOwnProperty` doesn't.

Comment: I should point out that you can define a property to hold the value known as `undefined`. JavaScript, yeah!